# What is the difference between IQueryable<T> and IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: .net, linq, .net-3.5, ienumerable, iqueryable

What is the difference between `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`?

---

See also [What's the difference between IQueryable and IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433306/whats-the-difference-between-iqueryable-and-ienumerable?rq=1) that overlaps with this question.

Comment: In the mean time, consensus has grown that this type of questions isn't on-topic any more.

Answer (score 301):

First of all, [`IQueryable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx) *extends* the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, so anything you can do with a "plain" `IEnumerable<T>`, you can also do with an `IQueryable<T>`.

`IEnumerable<T>` just has a `GetEnumerator()` method that returns an `Enumerator<T>` for which you can call its `MoveNext()` method to iterate through a sequence of *T*.

What `IQueryable<T>` has that `IEnumerable<T>` *doesn't* are two properties in particular—one that points to a **query provider** (e.g., a LINQ to SQL provider) and another one pointing to a **query expression** representing the `IQueryable<T>` object as a runtime-traversable abstract syntax tree that can be understood by the given query provider (for the most part, you can't give a LINQ to SQL expression to a LINQ to Entities provider without an exception being thrown).

The expression can simply be a constant expression of the object itself or a more complex tree of a composed set of query operators and operands. The query provider's `IQueryProvider.Execute()` or `IQueryProvider.CreateQuery()` methods are called with an *Expression* passed to it, and then either a query result or another `IQueryable` is returned, respectively.

Comment: Is there any benefit to using AsQueryable?

Comment: The only benefit is convenience. `AsQueryable()` will just cast an enumerable to a queryable and return it if it implements the `IQueryable` interface, otherwise it wraps it in a `ConstantExpression`, which is referred to in a returned  `EnumerableQuery` object.

Comment: Related question: [IEnumerable<T> and IQueryable<T> clarification?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132888/ienumerablet-and-iqueryablet-clarification?lq=1)

Comment: Worth reading this [article](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/linq/I8SY160612-IEnumerable-VS-IQueryable.html)

Comment: @JenonD link is dead, here's the waybackmachine: https://web.archive.org/web/20160904162931/http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/linq/I8SY160612-IEnumerable-VS-IQueryable.html

Comment: Next two answers weren't clear enough. The best one for me was: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet/2876655#2876655

Answer (score 276):

This is a nice [video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfPGFapabAY) which demonstrates how these interfaces differ , worth a watch.

Below goes a long descriptive answer for it.

The first important point to remember is `IQueryable` interface inherits from `IEnumerable`, so whatever `IEnumerable` can do, `IQueryable` can also do.

[image]

There are many differences but let us discuss about the one big difference which makes  the biggest difference. **`IEnumerable`** interface is useful when your collection is loaded using `LINQ` or Entity framework and you want to apply filter on the collection.

Consider the below simple code which uses `IEnumerable` with entity framework. It’s using a `Where` filter to get records whose `EmpId` is `2`.

```
EmpEntities ent = new EmpEntities();
IEnumerable<Employee> emp = ent.Employees; 
IEnumerable<Employee> temp = emp.Where(x => x.Empid == 2).ToList<Employee>();
```

This where filter is executed on the client side where the `IEnumerable` code is. In other words all the data is fetched from the database and then at the client its scans and gets the record with `EmpId` is `2`.

[image]

But now see the below code we have changed **`IEnumerable`** to **`IQueryable`**. It creates a SQL Query at the server side and only necessary data is sent to the client side.

```
EmpEntities ent = new EmpEntities();
IQueryable<Employee> emp = ent.Employees;
IQueryable<Employee> temp =  emp.Where(x => x.Empid == 2).ToList<Employee>();
```

[image]

So the difference between `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` is about where the filter logic is executed. One executes on the client side and the other executes  on the database.

So if you working with only in-memory data collection `IEnumerable` is a good choice but if you want to query data collection which is connected with database `IQueryable is a better choice as it reduces network traffic and uses the power of SQL language.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for wonderful explanation. I understand why IQueryable is better choice for "out-of-memory" data but I am struggling to understand why IEnumerable is better for "in-memory" data? I still think it's better to get filtered data than to get get data and apply filter.

Comment: when it's "in-memory" it doesn't really matter. the data is already on the memory, on what exact time it being filtered isn't matter.

Comment: @Imad For example, projecting data by converting entity DateTimeOffset to DateTime can't feasibly be done using IQueryable or with EntityFunctions. The best way is to to AsEnumerable() the entity object, then Select() into a viewmodel that contains the DateTime. This process uses in-memory functions.

Answer (score 231):

The primary difference is that the LINQ operators for `IQueryable<T>` take `Expression` objects instead of delegates, meaning the custom query logic it receives, e.g., a predicate or value selector, is in the form of an expression tree instead of a delegate to a method.

- `IEnumerable<T>` is great for working with sequences that are iterated in-memory, but
- `IQueryable<T>` allows for out-of memory things like a remote data source, such as a database or web service.

#### Query execution:

- Where the execution of a query is going to be performed **"in process"**, typically all that's required is the code (as code) to execute each part of the query.
- Where the execution will be performed **out-of-process**, the logic of the query has to be represented in data such that the LINQ provider can convert it into the appropriate form for the out-of-memory execution - whether that's an LDAP query, SQL or whatever.

More in:

- [LINQ : `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>`](https://web.archive.org/web/20200720162730/https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19666.net-framework-ienumerable-t-vs-iqueryable-t.aspx)
- [C# 3.0 and LINQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20201127014808/https://odetocode.com/Articles/738.aspx).
- "[Returning `IEnumerable<T>` vs `IQueryable<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet/2876655#2876655)"
- [Reactive Programming for .NET and C# Developers - An Introduction To `IEnumerable`, `IQueryable`, `IObservable`, and `IQbservable`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/646361/Reactive-Programming-For-NET-And-Csharp-Developers)
- 2008: "[THE MOST FUNNY INTERFACE OF THE YEAR … `IQUERYABLE<T>`](https://web.archive.org/web/20170708130544/http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/08/15/the-most-funny-interface-of-the-year-iqueryable-lt-t-gt.aspx)" from [Bart De Smet](http://bartdesmet.net).

[image: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/646361/WhatHowWhere.jpg]

Comment: I like the mention of out-of-memory operations. It clarifies a real practical difference in use.

Comment: Instead of taking delegates as parameters like the IEnumerable<T> Where method does, IQueryable<T> will take Expression<TDelegate> parameters. We are not passing code into IQueryable<T>, we are passing expression trees (code as data) for the LINQ provider to analyze.
[C# 3.0 and LINQ](http://odetocode.com/Articles/738.aspx)

Comment: something is up with your image link, its not rendering in the post body for some reason http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/646361/WhatHowWhere.jpg

Comment: @joey Yet, I see that image just fine in this answer: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2DAqv.jpg

Comment: This answer is good, until the noisy diagram representing concurrency, pull vs push, `IObservable<T>`, with only some 5% of the diagram having to do with `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>`; the same applies to the link to "Reactive Programming", where the distinction between `IEnumerable<T>` / `IQueryable<T>` only serves as an intro to Reactive Extensions. Also I would suggest including a link to [The most funny interface of the year ... `IQueryable<T>`](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/08/15/the-most-funny-interface-of-the-year-iqueryable-lt-t-gt.aspx) by Bart de Smet.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Thank you for the feedback. I have included your link in the answer. I would welcome an edit from you to replace the picture by one more relevant.

Answer (score 63):

**IEnumerable:** 
IEnumerable is best suitable for working with in-memory collection (or local queries).
IEnumerable doesn’t move between items, it is forward only collection.

**IQueryable:**
IQueryable best suits for remote data source, like a database or web service  (or remote queries).
IQueryable is a very powerful feature that enables a variety of interesting deferred execution scenarios (like paging and composition based queries).

So when you have to simply iterate through the in-memory collection, use IEnumerable, if you need to do any manipulation with the collection like Dataset and other data sources, use IQueryable

Comment: Doesn't IEnumerable use deferred execution?

Comment: Deferred execution is available both in IEnumerable and IQueryable. Further interesting info can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet

Answer (score 24):

In simple words other major difference is that  IEnumerable execute select query on server side, load data in-memory on client side and then filter data while IQueryable execute select query on server side with all filters.

Answer (score 19):

In real life, if you are using a ORM like LINQ-to-SQL

- If you create an IQueryable, then the query may be converted to sql and run on the database server
- If you create an IEnumerable, then all rows will be pulled into memory as objects before running the query.

In both cases if you don't call a `ToList()` or `ToArray()` then query will be executed each time it is used, so, say, you have an `IQueryable<T>` and you fill 4 list boxes from it, then the query will be run against the database 4 times.

Also if you extent your query:

```
q.Where(x.name = "a").ToList()
```

Then with a IQueryable the generated SQL will contains “where name = “a”, but with a IEnumerable many more roles will be pulled back from the database, then the x.name = “a” check will be done by .NET.

Answer (score 18):

We use `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` to manipulate the data that is retrieved from database. `IQueryable` inherits from `IEnumerable`, so `IQueryable` does contain all the `IEnumerable` features. The major difference between `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` is that `IQueryable` executes query with filters whereas `IEnumerable` executes the query first and then it filters the data based on conditions.

Find more detailed differentiation below :

**IEnumerable**

1. `IEnumerable` exists in the `System.Collections` namespace
2. `IEnumerable` execute a select query on the server side, load data in-memory on a client-side and then filter data
3. `IEnumerable` is suitable for querying data from in-memory collections like List, Array
4. `IEnumerable` is beneficial for LINQ to Object and LINQ to XML queries

**IQueryable**

1. `IQueryable` exists in the `System.Linq` namespace
2. `IQueryable` executes a 'select query' on server-side with all filters
3. `IQueryable` is suitable for querying data from out-memory (like remote database, service) collections
4. `IQueryable` is beneficial for LINQ to SQL queries

So `IEnumerable` is generally used for dealing with in-memory collection, whereas, `IQueryable` is generally used to manipulate collections.

Answer (score 16):

Below mentioned small test might help you understand one aspect of difference between **IQueryable<T>** and **IEnumerable<T>**. I've reproduced this answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43623973/465053) post where I was trying to add corrections to someone else's post

I created following structure in DB (DDL script):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee]([PersonId] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,[Salary] [int] NOT NULL)
```

Here is the record insertion script (DML script):

```
INSERT INTO [EfTest].[dbo].[Employee] ([PersonId],[Salary])VALUES(1, 20)
INSERT INTO [EfTest].[dbo].[Employee] ([PersonId],[Salary])VALUES(2, 30)
INSERT INTO [EfTest].[dbo].[Employee] ([PersonId],[Salary])VALUES(3, 40)
INSERT INTO [EfTest].[dbo].[Employee] ([PersonId],[Salary])VALUES(4, 50)
INSERT INTO [EfTest].[dbo].[Employee] ([PersonId],[Salary])VALUES(5, 60)
GO
```

Now my goal was to get top 2 records from **Employee** table in database. I created a new C# console application in Visual Studio (VS). Then, I added an ADO.NET Entity Data Model XML (EDMX) item pointing to **Employee** table in the database. Now I can start writing LINQ queries.

**Case I:** Code for **IQueryable** route

```
using (var efContext = new EfTestEntities())
{
    IQueryable<int> employees = from e in efContext.Employees  select e.Salary;
    employees = employees.Take(2);

    foreach (var item in employees)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Before running this program, I had started a session of SQL Query profiler on the SQL Server instance. Here is the summary of execution:

1. Total number of queries fired: **1**
2. Query text:

   ```
   SELECT TOP (2) [c].[Salary] AS [Salary] FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [c]
   ```

We can see that **IQueryable** is smart enough to apply the `Top (2)` clause on database server side itself. So it brings only 2 out of 5 records over the network. No more in-memory filtering is required on the client side.

**Case II:** Code for **IEnumerable** route

```
using (var efContext = new EfTestEntities())
{
    IEnumerable<int> employees = from e in efContext.Employees  select e.Salary;
    employees = employees.Take(2);

    foreach (var item in employees)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Summary of execution in this case:

1. Total number of queries fired: **1**
2. Query text captured in SQL profiler:

   ```
   SELECT [Extent1].[Salary] AS [Salary] FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Extent1]
   ```

Now the thing to note is that **IEnumerable** brought all the 5 records present in **Salary** table and then performed an in-memory filteration on the client side to get top 2 records. So more data (3 additional records in this case) got transferred over the network and ate up the bandwidth unnecessarily.

Answer (score 11):

IEnumerable is refering to a collection but IQueryable is just a query and it will be generated inside a Expression Tree.we will run this query to get data from database.

Answer (score 8):

Here is what I wrote on a similar post (on this topic). (And no, I don't usually quote myself, but these are very good articles.)

"This article is helpful:
[IQueryable vs IEnumerable in LINQ-to-SQL](https://web.archive.org/web/20120401112218/http://www.hamishgraham.net/post/RE-IQueryable-vs-IEnumerable-in-LINQ-to-SQL-queries.aspx).

Quoting that article, 'As per the MSDN documentation, calls made on IQueryable operate by building up the internal expression tree instead.
"These methods that extend IQueryable(Of T) do not perform any querying directly. Instead, their functionality is to build an Expression object, which is an expression tree that represents the cumulative query. "'

Expression trees are a very important construct in C# and on the .NET platform. (They are important in general, but C# makes them very useful.) To better understand the difference, I recommend reading about the differences between *expressions* and *statements* [in the official C# 5.0 specification here.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) For advanced theoretical concepts that branch into lambda calculus, expressions enable support for methods as first-class objects. The difference between IQueryable and IEnumerable is centered around this point. IQueryable builds expression trees whereas IEnumerable does not, at least not in general terms for those of us who don't work in the secret labs of Microsoft.

Here is another very useful article that details the differences from a push vs. pull perspective. (By "push" vs. "pull," I am referring to direction of data flow. [Reactive Programming Techniques for .NET and C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/646361/Reactive-Programming-for-NET-and-Csharp-Developers)

Here is a very good article that details the differences between statement lambdas and expression lambdas and discusses the concepts of expression tress in greater depth: [Revisiting C# delegates, expression trees, and lambda statements vs. lambda expressions.](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2010/09/revisiting-few-c-concepts-delegates.html)."

Answer (score 3):

IQueryable is faster than IEnumerable if we are dealing with huge amounts of data from database because,IQueryable gets only required data from database where as IEnumerable gets all the data regardless of the necessity from the database

Answer (score 0):

ienumerable:when we want to deal with inprocess memory, i.e without dataconnection
iqueryable:when to deal with sql server, i.e with data connection
ilist : operations like add object, delete object etc

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer:

`IEnumerable<T>` is for iterating over **in-memory collections**, while `IQueryable<T>` is for querying data from out-of-memory sources and offers query translation, deferred execution, etc. `IQueryable<T>` extends `IEnumerable<T>`, adding a query provider and a query expression for more complex queries.

### More detailed answer:

`IEnumerable<T>` is an interface for iterating over in-memory collections like lists, best for data already loaded in memory. It has a `GetEnumerator()` method for iteration. `IQueryable<T>`, extending `IEnumerable<T>`, is used for querying data from out-of-memory sources like databases. It has additional properties: a query provider (like a LINQ to SQL provider) and a query expression, representing the `IQueryable<T>` object as a runtime-traversable abstract syntax tree. The query provider’s `IQueryProvider.Execute()` or IQueryProvider.CreateQuery()` methods are called with an Expression, returning either a query result or another IQueryable.