# Using IQueryable with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

What is the use of `IQueryable` in the context of LINQ?

Is it used for developing extension methods or any other purpose?

Answer (score 577, accepted):

[Marc Gravell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578778/using-iqueryable-with-linq/1578809#1578809) is very complete, but I thought I'd add something about this from the user's point of view, as well...

---

The main difference, from a user's perspective, is that, when you use `IQueryable<T>` (with a provider that supports things correctly), you can save a lot of resources.

For example, if you're working against a remote database, with many ORM systems, you have the option of fetching data from a table in two ways, one which returns `IEnumerable<T>`, and one which returns an `IQueryable<T>`.  Say, for example, you have a Products table, and you want to get all of the products whose cost is >$25.

If you do:

```
 IEnumerable<Product> products = myORM.GetProducts();
 var productsOver25 = products.Where(p => p.Cost >= 25.00);
```

What happens here, is the database loads all of the products, and passes them across the wire to your program.  Your program then filters the data.  In essence, the database does a `SELECT * FROM Products`, and returns EVERY product to you.

With the right `IQueryable<T>` provider, on the other hand, you can do:

```
 IQueryable<Product> products = myORM.GetQueryableProducts();
 var productsOver25 = products.Where(p => p.Cost >= 25.00);
```

The code looks the same, but the difference here is that the SQL executed will be `SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Cost >= 25`.

From your POV as a developer, this looks the same.  However, from a performance standpoint, you may only return 2 records across the network instead of 20,000....

Comment: Where is the definition of "GetQueryableProducts(); " ?

Comment: @StackOverflowUser It's intended to be any method that returns an `IQueryable<Product>` - would be specific to your ORM or repository, etc.

Comment: right. but you mentioned where clause after this function call. So system is still unaware of the filter. I mean it still fetch all records of products. right?

Comment: @StackOverflowUser No - that's the beauty of IQueryable<T> - it can be setup to evaluate *when you get the results* - which means the Where clause, used after the fact, will still get translated into a SQL statement run on the server, and pull only the required elements across the wire...

Comment: can you please give some example, what to write in this function "GetQueryableProducts".

Comment: @StackOverflowUser It depends on what technology you're using.  For example, with EF, you could just return an ObjectQuery<T>, ie: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345303.aspx

Comment: Does it means that we are not in database till this line `IQueryable<Product> products = myORM.GetQueryableProducts();` and when this executes `var productsOver25 = products.Where(p => p.Cost >= 25.00);` we are going to database ?

Comment: @Testing You're actually still not going to the DB.  Until you actually enumerate the results (ie: use a `foreach`, or call `ToList()`), you don't actually hit the DB.

Comment: @testing is correct. You can examine this by using the SQL Server Profiler

Comment: The point is that your query gets executed when the iteration starts (when you call `ToArray()`, `ToList()`, `First()`, `SingleOrDefault()`, etc...), until that point you just build up the query by using `Where(...)`, `Take(...)`, `Select(...)`.

Comment: @ReedCopsey With an `IEnumerable` when you iterate over the results, will it still fetch all data first and then filter it compared to fetching only the data needed by iterating `ÌQueryable`?

Comment: @alexander no, with iqueryable, iterating will fetch all results, too.

Comment: What is important to mention here (I think no one talks about in comments) is the keyword "deferred". The difference between IQueryable and IEnumerable is IQueryable is meant to be used while no deferred execution has occurred. The answer is complete but I think it's worth to mention. Read this post for more information: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-deferred-execution or this one https://www.dotnetcurry.com/linq/750/deferred-vs-immediate-query-execution-linq

Answer (score 209):

In essence its job is very similar to `IEnumerable<T>` - to represent a queryable data source - the difference being that the various LINQ methods (on `Queryable`) can be more specific, to build the query using `Expression` trees rather than delegates (which is what `Enumerable` uses).

The expression trees can be inspected by your chosen LINQ provider and turned into an *actual* query - although that is a black art in itself.

This is really down to the `ElementType`, `Expression` and `Provider` - but in reality you *rarely* need to care about this as a **user**. Only a LINQ *implementer* needs to know the gory details.

---

Re comments; I'm not quite sure what you want by way of example, but consider LINQ-to-SQL; the central object here is a `DataContext`, which represents our database-wrapper. This typically has a property per table (for example, `Customers`), and a table implements `IQueryable<Customer>`. But we don't use that much directly; consider:

```
using(var ctx = new MyDataContext()) {
    var qry = from cust in ctx.Customers
              where cust.Region == "North"
              select new { cust.Id, cust.Name };
    foreach(var row in qry) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", row.Id, row.Name);
    }
}
```

this becomes (by the C# compiler):

```
var qry = ctx.Customers.Where(cust => cust.Region == "North")
                .Select(cust => new { cust.Id, cust.Name });
```

which is again interpreted (by the C# compiler) as:

```
var qry = Queryable.Select(
              Queryable.Where(
                  ctx.Customers,
                  cust => cust.Region == "North"),
              cust => new { cust.Id, cust.Name });
```

Importantly, the static methods on `Queryable` take expression trees, which - rather than regular IL, get compiled to an object model. For example - just looking at the "Where", this gives us something comparable to:

```
var cust = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "cust");
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer,bool>>(
                  Expression.Equal(
                      Expression.Property(cust, "Region"),
                      Expression.Constant("North")
                  ), cust);

... Queryable.Where(ctx.Customers, lambda) ...
```

Didn't the compiler do a lot for us? This object model can be torn apart, inspected for what it means, and put back together again by the TSQL generator - giving something like:

```
 SELECT c.Id, c.Name
 FROM [dbo].[Customer] c
 WHERE c.Region = 'North'
```

(the string might end up as a parameter; I can't remember)

None of this would be possible if we had just used a delegate. And *this* is the point of `Queryable` / `IQueryable<T>`: it provides the entry-point for using expression trees.

All this is very complex, so it is a good job that the compiler makes it nice and easy for us.

For more information, look at "[C# in Depth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182471)" or "[LINQ in Action](http://linqinaction.net/)", both of which provide coverage of these topics.

Comment: If you don't mind can you update me with simple understandable example(if you have time).

Comment: Can you explain "Where is the definition of "GetQueryableProducts(); " ?" in Mr Reed Copsey reply

Comment: Enjoyed the line of translating expressions to a query is "black art in itself"...a lot of truth to that

Comment: Why would none of it be possible if you had used a delegate?

Comment: @Backwards_Dave because a delegate points (essentially) to IL, and IL isn't sufficiently expressive to make it reasonable to try to deconstruct the intent sufficiently to build SQL. IL also allows *too many* things - i.e. most things that can be expressed in IL *couldn't* be expressed in the limited syntax that it is reasonable to turn into things like SQL

Comment: tl;dr "And this is the point of Queryable / IQueryable<T>: it provides the entry-point for using expression trees." https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/expression-tree From C# using LINQ to the Database. Right?

Answer (score 21):

Although [Reed Copsey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578778/using-iqueryable-with-linq/1578809#1578977) and [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578778/using-iqueryable-with-linq/1578809#1578809) already described about `IQueryable` (and also `IEnumerable`) enough,mI want to add little more here by providing a small example on `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` as many users asked for it

**Example**: I have created two table in database

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee]([PersonId] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,[Gender] [nchar](1) NOT NULL)
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person]([PersonId] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,[FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,[LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL)
```

The Primary key(`PersonId`) of table `Employee` is also a forgein key(`personid`) of table `Person`

Next i added ado.net entity model in my application and create below service class on that

```
public class SomeServiceClass
{   
    public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployeeAndPersonDetailIQueryable(IEnumerable<int> employeesToCollect)
    {
        DemoIQueryableEntities db = new DemoIQueryableEntities();
        var allDetails = from Employee e in db.Employees
                         join Person p in db.People on e.PersonId equals p.PersonId
                         where employeesToCollect.Contains(e.PersonId)
                         select e;
        return allDetails;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployeeAndPersonDetailIEnumerable(IEnumerable<int> employeesToCollect)
    {
        DemoIQueryableEntities db = new DemoIQueryableEntities();
        var allDetails = from Employee e in db.Employees
                         join Person p in db.People on e.PersonId equals p.PersonId
                         where employeesToCollect.Contains(e.PersonId)
                         select e;
        return allDetails;
    }
}
```

they contains same linq. It called in `program.cs` as defined below

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeServiceClass s= new SomeServiceClass(); 

        var employeesToCollect= new []{0,1,2,3};

        //IQueryable execution part
        var IQueryableList = s.GetEmployeeAndPersonDetailIQueryable(employeesToCollect).Where(i => i.Gender=="M");            
        foreach (var emp in IQueryableList)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("ID:{0}, EName:{1},Gender:{2}", emp.PersonId, emp.Person.FirstName, emp.Gender);
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine("IQueryable contain {0} row in result set", IQueryableList.Count());

        //IEnumerable execution part
        var IEnumerableList = s.GetEmployeeAndPersonDetailIEnumerable(employeesToCollect).Where(i => i.Gender == "M");
        foreach (var emp in IEnumerableList)
        {
           System.Console.WriteLine("ID:{0}, EName:{1},Gender:{2}", emp.PersonId, emp.Person.FirstName, emp.Gender);
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine("IEnumerable contain {0} row in result set", IEnumerableList.Count());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The output is same for both obviously

```
ID:1, EName:Ken,Gender:M  
ID:3, EName:Roberto,Gender:M  
IQueryable contain 2 row in result set  
ID:1, EName:Ken,Gender:M  
ID:3, EName:Roberto,Gender:M  
IEnumerable contain 2 row in result set
```

So the question is what/where is the difference? It does not seem to
 have any difference right? Really!!

Let's have a look on sql queries generated and executed by entity
 framwork 5 during these period

**IQueryable execution part**

```
--IQueryableQuery1 
SELECT 
[Extent1].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], 
[Extent1].[Gender] AS [Gender]
FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[PersonId] IN (0,1,2,3)) AND (N'M' = [Extent1].[Gender])

--IQueryableQuery2
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[PersonId] IN (0,1,2,3)) AND (N'M' = [Extent1].[Gender])
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

**IEnumerable execution part**

```
--IEnumerableQuery1
SELECT 
[Extent1].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], 
[Extent1].[Gender] AS [Gender]
FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[PersonId] IN (0,1,2,3)

--IEnumerableQuery2
SELECT 
[Extent1].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], 
[Extent1].[Gender] AS [Gender]
FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[PersonId] IN (0,1,2,3)
```

**Common script for both execution part**

```
/* these two query will execute for both IQueryable or IEnumerable to get details from Person table
   Ignore these two queries here because it has nothing to do with IQueryable vs IEnumerable
--ICommonQuery1 
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName]
FROM [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[PersonId] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=1

--ICommonQuery2
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName]
FROM [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[PersonId] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=3
*/
```

---

So you have few questions now, let me guess those and try to answer them

**Why are different scripts generated for same result?**

Lets find out some points here,

all queries has one common part

`WHERE [Extent1].[PersonId] IN (0,1,2,3)`

why? Because both function `IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployeeAndPersonDetailIQueryable` and 
`IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployeeAndPersonDetailIEnumerable` of `SomeServiceClass` contains one common line in linq queries

`where employeesToCollect.Contains(e.PersonId)`

Than why is the
`AND (N'M' = [Extent1].[Gender])` part is missing in `IEnumerable` execution part, while in both function calling we used `Where(i => i.Gender == "M") in`program.cs`

> Now we are in the point where difference came between `IQueryable` and
>   `IEnumerable`

What entity framwork does when an `IQueryable` method called, it tooks linq statement written inside the method and try to find out if more linq expressions are defined on the resultset, it then gathers all linq queries defined until the result need to fetch and constructs more appropriate sql query to execute.

It provide a lots of benefits like,

- only those rows populated by sql server which could be valid by the
  whole linq query execution
- helps sql server performance by not selecting unnecessary rows
- network cost get reduce

like here in example sql server returned to application only two rows after IQueryable execution` but returned *THREE* rows for IEnumerable query why?

In case of  `IEnumerable` method, entity framework took linq statement written inside the method and constructs sql query when result need to fetch. it does not include rest linq part to constructs the sql query. Like here no filtering is done in sql server on column `gender`.

But the outputs are same? Because 'IEnumerable filters the result further in application level after retrieving result from sql server

**SO,** what should someone choose?
I personally prefer to define function result as `IQueryable<T>` because there are lots of benefit it has over `IEnumerable` like, you could join two or more IQueryable functions, which generate more specific script to sql server.

Here in example you can see an `IQueryable Query(IQueryableQuery2)` generates a more specific script than `IEnumerable query(IEnumerableQuery2)` which is much more acceptable in my point of view.

Comment: I know I am coming late to the party, but I was wondering if you have any thoughts about the positive/benefits of using IEnumerable and on which scenario do you think it could be beneficial to use over IQueryable.

Comment: @CesarB short ans->https://stackoverflow.com/a/55631618/2052085, long ans: If you are using dbcontext or query to any db directly use IQueryable, if searching within list of objects or xml(in memory) use ienumerable

Answer (score 2):

It allows for further querying further down the line.  If this was beyond a service boundary say, then the user of this IQueryable object would be allowed to do more with it.

For instance if you were using lazy loading with nhibernate this might result in graph being loaded when/if needed.