# I want to get all the rows from table using entity framework but I'm getting error in postman

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, entity-framework

**Visual Studio Code.**

```
namespace MlaWebApi.Controllers
{
    public class PostController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public List<post> PostDescription()
        {

            using (MlaDatabaseDemoEntities context = new MlaDatabaseDemoEntities())
            {
                var postDesc = context.posts.ToList();

                return postDesc;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**Error in postman:**

> {
>       "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>       "ExceptionMessage": "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
>       "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
>       "StackTrace": null,
>       "InnerException": {
>           "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>           "ExceptionMessage": "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.",
>           "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
>           "StackTrace": "   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract.CreateWrapper(Object list)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.<>c__DisplayClassd.b__c()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously(Action action, CancellationToken token)"
>       }
>   }

Comment: try to declare ``postDesc`` before ``using``.

Comment: Still getting same error

Comment: Try to change return type to``ienumerable<post>`` for the action and delete ``.tolist()`` because when calling it the context has already disposed. or create new model post class and convert the post entity to it and return it.

Comment: Same error in postman. Is there any JSON related problem?

Comment: Try solutions in this question, I don't have EF so I can't test, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617698/the-operation-cannot-be-completed-because-the-dbcontext-has-been-disposed-error