# How to get data from IQueryable?

Tags: c#

I called a method that returns IQueryable. e.g
var x = acDAL.GetData();
It returns 3 tables data by joining them. and I want to get data from this IQueryable for example

```
var x = acDAL.GetData(); 
foreach(var item in x) 
{ 
    int id=item.Id; 
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578778/using-iqueryable-with-linq

Comment: It depends on what kind of data you have inside your `IQueryable`. Can you provide more information of what happen inside your `GetData` method?

Comment: It returns 3 tables data by joining them. and I want to get data from this IQueryable like if
var x = acDAL.GetData();
foreach( var a in x)
{
  int id=a.Id;
}

Comment: what do you want to do with your data and what does it look like?

Comment: It returns 3 tables data by joining them. and I want to get data from this IQueryable like if var x = acDAL.GetData(); foreach( var a in x) { int id=a.Id; }

Comment: please update your question to include this new information.

Comment: I have updated. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You give the example:

```
var x = acDAL.GetData();
foreach(var a in x) {
    int id=a.Id;
}
```

But most if that will already work, especially since IQueryable implements IEnumerable. The problem is the .Id

You have two choices there:

- know the T, and cast to IQueryable-of-T
- use dynamic

The latter only involves changing the `var` in your example to `dynamic`:

```
var x = acDAL.GetData();
foreach(dynamic a in x) {
    int id=a.Id;
}
```

The former involves knowing the object - try a.GetType() to see what it is. Then:

```
var x = acDAL.GetData();
foreach(SomeType a in x) {
    int id=a.Id;
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
var x = (IQueryable<SomeType>)acDAL.GetData();
foreach(var a in x) {
    int id=a.Id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc for reply
For you dynamic solution it gives me error of 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Id'.
and a.GetType() is +  a.GetType() {<>f__AnonymousTypeb3`23[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal],System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean],System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean],System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],} dynamic {System.RuntimeType}

Comment: @user the dynamic approach should work fine if it actually had an Id in the projection. Anonymous types are a pain to work with if exposed outside of their context. What does a.GetType().GetProperty("Id") return? Null? Or non-null?

Comment: a.GetType().GetProperty("Id") it returns {Int32 Id}