# OrderBy with Dynamic Linq

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, dynamic-linq

I am trying to sort some data from entity before passing them to another function. Both tableName and columnName are selected dynamically. This is what I'm doing:

```
string tableName = cboSelectTable.Text.ToString();
var comboBoxColumn = from a in Context.RULES where 
                     a.ISCOMBOBOXCOLUMN == "Y" select a.COLUMN;

foreach (var colName in comboBoxColumn)
  {
    var getTableName = entityModel.GetType()
                                  .GetProperty(tableName)
                                  .GetValue(entityModel, null);
    var getData = ((IQueryable<object>)getTableName)
                                      .Where(colName + "!=null")
                                      .Select(colName)
                                      .Distinct()
                                      .OrderBy('"'+ colName +'"');
    dgvCboColumn(getData, colName);
  }
```

But this is not sorting the data. I also tried some other methods too, but couldn't figure it out. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you try `.OrderBy(colName)` ?

Comment: yes, it throws exception that the column name does not exist in String[at index 0].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You can simply place the `Select` after the `OrderBy`:</strike>

```
var getData = ((IQueryable<object>)getTableName)
                  .Where(colName + "!=null")
                  .OrderBy(colName)
                  .Select(colName)
                  .Distinct();
```

This will allow you to reference the column name. (doesn't seem to work for some reason).

Alternatively, you can reference the *current instance*:

```
var getData = ((IQueryable<object>)getTableName)
                  .Where(colName + "!=null")
                  .Select(colName)
                  .Distinct()
                  .OrderBy("it");
```

Comment: Its not sorting the data, giving a list of unsorted data. Same as before.

Comment: Weird. Did you try both approaches?

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice your update. The second approach works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that is the way, .OrderBy(...) works. Try ordering by an attribute:

```
SomeList.OrderBy(l => l.SomeAttribute);
```

I suspect ordering by a string results in each element being ordered by the same attribute, thus not ordering at all. In addition, I am not sure, if your where-clause works like that.

There is another relevant SO question already answered. You might want to have a look at it: [click me!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578778/using-iqueryable-with-linq)

Comment: This is using `System.Linq.Dynamic`, a small library on top of LINQ. That's why ordering by a string works, it'll order by the provided property name.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of the difference.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to use ( l => l.someCol) in this case.