# c# linq, what is the effect of using .where() on .Get()?

Tags: c#, linq

A question asked to the floor in our office was:

What is the difference between

**Method 1**

```
var team = _db.Get<ClientCreateDefaults>(c => c.ClientRef == newCase.ClientRef &&
    c.WorkTypeCode == newCase.WorkTypeCode);
```

**Method 2**

```
var team = _db.Get<ClientCreateDefaults>(c => c.ClientRef ==
    newCase.ClientRef).Where(w => w.WorkTypeCode == newCase.WorkTypeCode);
```

**Method 3**

```
var team = _db.Get<ClientCreateDefaults>().Where(w => w.WorkTypeCode ==
    newCase.WorkTypeCode).Where(c => c.ClientRef == newCase.ClientRef);
```

An answer was given:

> If this is our `DataContext`:
>
> The first one, the conditions will all be translated into SQL, so the filtering will happen on the db server.
>
> The second one only does the first one on the db server and then filters by `WorkTypeCode` on the client side.
>
> The third one will filter all client side and get all of the items from the db.

Is this correct? Does linq really bring whole datasets to the client side?

Comment: you are using `LINQ to SQL` not EF right?

Comment: It would rather depend whether it's `Enumerable.Where` or `Queryable.Where`. You might want to look at [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578778/using-iqueryable-with-linq).

Comment: Why don't you use a Sql Profiler, and then you can answer your own question?

Comment: You're asking strangers on the internet whether the experts on your own systems are correct or not?  How should we know; we're not experts on your system!

Comment: I believe all of those will be the same. If your collection is implementing `IQueryable`, it will filter the data in SQL (db). If your collection is using `IEnumerable`, it's pretty much doing a `select *` in SQL so you will get every record unfiltered; the filtering will then occur outside of SQL and when requested at runtime.
I think [this article](http://blog.falafel.com/understanding-ienumerable-iqueryable-c/) can explain it better.

Comment: @Arman.  Thanks for the comment, it was most helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get` is your code, not the code of LINQ 2 SQL. According to the experts explanation it returns an `IEnumerable`. Once it returns you leave the realm of LINQ 2 SQL and enter LINQ to Objects. That's why the appended filtering is done on the client.

This looks like a generic repository pattern.