# Asp.net: Which Better Bind ListView By Model Binding or By DataSource?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, listview, webforms, model-binding

I build a asp.net Web Application Webforms with  Entity Framework, I find Two Way to bind the ListView for: 
1- By DataSource Like this

```
 void Bind()
    {
        var search = db.Search.Where(k => k.RequestId == RequestId);
        lstSearch.DataSource = search.ToList();
        lstSearch.DataBind();
    }
```

2- By use SelectMethod Like this

```
public IQueryable<Search> BindOrders()
{
    var search = db.Search.Where(k => k.RequestId == 12).AsQueryable();

    return search;
}
```

which one is best and why?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectMethod` and many other features for binding data to web controls were introduced in `.NET Framework 4.5` as a strongly-typed data-binding. Those features let's you handle the data you create/delete/modify/filter from/to web controls in a clean and maintainable way.

In the other hand `DataSource` way is the old way of binding data to web controls.

I advise you to read [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/web-forms-model-binding-part-1-selecting-data-asp-net-vnext-series) blog which goes in detail about the subject (ScottGu's):

> The new Model Binding support in ASP.NET vNext is a nice evolution of
>   the existing Web Forms data-binding system.  It borrows concepts and
>   features from the Model Binding system in ASP.NET MVC (you'll see this
>   more in later posts), and makes working with code-focused data-access
>   paradigms simpler and more flexible.

Also, check for the [advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578778/using-iqueryable-with-linq) of using `IQueryable<Object>`:

> The main difference, from a user's perspective, is that, when you use
>   IQueryable (with a provider that supports things correctly), you
>   can save a lot of resources.