# using Any() with IQueryable List takes long time when executing?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
List<int> projectIds=GetProjectsIds();// size is about 100,000 int value.
List<int> userIds=GetUsersIds();// size is about 100,000 int value.
List<int> nextIds=GetNextIds();// size is about 100,000 int value.


var IQueryList= db.Users.Where(obj=> projectIds.any(x=>x==obj.ProjectID) 
                                    || userIds.any(x=>x==obj.UserId) 
                                    || nextIds.any(x=>x==obj.NextId) );
```

it takes really long time when converting the `IQueryable` to `List`.

```
var YearsGroup = IQueryList.GroupBy(x => x.CreatedOn.Year)
                           .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
                           .ToList()
                           .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn.Year);
// it's taking about 3 seconds to get executed.
```

How can I solve this issues, is there any other ways that I can apply to my code?

Comment: The above code does not compile. _`any` as an example._

Comment: what's the code of `GetXXXIds()`? Probably you could run that in your database instead of fetching all these values into your application

Comment: I'm actually surprised it only takes 3 seconds, this code is actually translated to a `WHERE.. IN` with 300,000 integers!

Comment: `IQueryable` to `List` is bringing data to memory, no more remote processing, so it depends upon, how much data you are bringing, what kind of network, which will cause time delay

Comment: If you change `projectIds` etc to `HashSet` rather than `List` and then use `Contains`, how long does the code take to run? How long does `var bob = db.Users.ToList();` take to run?

Comment: Take a step back, tell us what you want `YearsGroup` to contain and why.

Comment: @GSerg How did you come to the conclusion the OP was using L2S? To be honest, I am assuming the logic is occurring client-side rather than server-side (hence why I asked how long `ToList` is taking, since you can't pass 300,000 parameters in most databases).

Comment: @more2know What database platform are you using (SQL Server? something else?)? Are you using Linq to SQL? Entity Framework? EF Core?

Comment: Why do you build those three lists with 300000 ID's in memory and then query the database with each and every one on three different columns? Are you sure that you can't get them in the database and link to the user-table?

Comment: You should really execute the `ToList` at the end of the query. For two reasons: you get a collection as result and not a query which would be executed again and again whenever you use it(for example with `foreach(var grp in OrderByDescending)...)`. You would also execute the `OrderByDescending` in the database and not in memory.

Comment: @TimSchmelter OrderBy is actually often faster to do on the client side. Sorting needs the whole sequence, so server can not start to send data unless it has it all. It is a pipelining killer.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek: sorting is a core discipline of a database. If that's too slow you have to determine why. My point was also that `YearsGroup` is not a list even if he used `ToList`. The `OrderByDescending`  at the end makes it a query. So he can't use any list methods and the query gets executed everytime he "touches" it. So if the in-memory-order is really useful here he should add another `ToList` at the end to "materialize" the query into a collection and he should replace the first ToList with AsEnumerable.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck it's solved after converting the query to list before applying the GroupBy, do you have any comment for this ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter thank you, I've just seen your comment, converting to list solved it.

Comment: @more2know Well the `Where` clause where you check the ID's is what surprised me that is so fast. If you want to see the actual query generated, you can do `var sqlQuery = IQueryList.ToString()`.

Comment: How many rows in the Users table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called [Abstraction leak](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/) and it is the result of switching between *Linq-To-Entities* (i.e. Entity Framework) into - *Linq-To-Objects*.

Basically what the law states is that developers of reliable software must learn the abstraction's underlying details anyway.

**Meaning**:

your abstraction exposes some of the implementation details and there is nothing you can do with it unfortunetly.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction):

> A leaky abstraction refers to any implemented abstraction, intended to
>   reduce (or hide) complexity, where the underlying details are not
>   completely hidden

One way to solve it is to create an object with good constraint and maintain linq queries with As less as conditions possible.

In your code you are using `Where` and `GroupBy` which might cause for the penalty in the abstraction leak:

```
List<int> projectIds=GetProjectsIds();// size is about 100,000 int value.
List<int> userIds=GetUsersIds();// size is about 100,000 int value.
List<int> nextIds=GetNextIds();// size is about 100,000 int value.

//Linq to sql statement
var IQueryList= db.Users.Where(obj=> projectIds.Any(x=>x==obj.ProjectID) 
                                    || userIds.Any(x=>x==obj.UserId) 
                                    || nextIds.Any(x=>x==obj.NextId) );

//Linq to object, possible abstraction leak.
var YearsGroup = IQueryList.GroupBy(x => x.CreatedOn.Year)
                           .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
                           .ToList()
                           .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn.Year);
```

Comment: @BarrJ thank you, do you suggest converting IQueryList to List before applying the GroupBy, like this .... 
var YearsGroup = IQueryList.ToList().GroupBy(x => x.CreatedOn.Year)....

Comment: I'd prefer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578778/using-iqueryable-with-linq/1578809#1578809 :)

Comment: @BarrJ converting it to a List before applying the GroupBy solved my problem, that's really strange, can you give more information about this issue ? thank you !

Comment: Read the article I posted in my answer, all is there :)