# LINQ - Minimize Records Returned - Correct Way to Write These Expressions

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-expressions

Employee is a sample entity type.

```
var r1 = (from c in _ctx select c).Skip(5).Take(5);  

// my intent is to pull the first record from the query  
var r2 = (from c in _ctx select c).FirstOrDefault<Employee>();   

// my intent is to pull the last record from the query.
// any good way to ask for the result back in the reverse   
// order of the natural sort without specifing a field/property name?  
var r3 = (from c in _ctx select c).LastOrDefault<Employee>();
```

Do these pull back the entire records (objects) and then filter?
What is the best way to write these so that the whole line is a LINQ expression?

Comment: Write a single foreach loop which iterates only once? Keep an internal counter perhaps.

Comment: Do you have a remote source?!?! (LINQ to SQL)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399410.aspx

Comment: salgo60, Yes these are LINQ to SQL expressions now. Could be LINQ to Entities later.

Comment: As I say below then you will have interpreted queries and as with local queries you have a deferred excecution model. The difference between a loacal and a intepreted is that when the interpreted query is excecuted then the whole question is seen as an unit and will traverse the whole expression tree and then excecute. The result will be yielded as a sequence...

Answer (score 2):

I believe that (assuming `_ctx` is a `DataContext`) the SQL generated will be mildly efficient.

Can I suggest that you run SQL Server Profiler while you run these bits of code?

I think the query for `r2` will be a simple `SELECT TOP (1)` statement.

`r1` has a chance of being efficient with:

```
SELECT TOP(5) [fields]
FROM (
       SELECT TOP (10) [fields]
       FROM [table]
       ORDER BY [identitycol] DESC
     )
```

`r3` looks like it may just select all and take the last record.

Try Profiler and see :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use IQueryable that means that you create a expression tree that will be run in the remote source

See [What is the difference between IQueryable<T> and IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet)

Good books tools c# 3.0 in a NutShell,LinqPad, LINQ in Action

Answer (score 0):

1. It filters records within database since `IQueryable` is used. However, @Codesleuth can be right concerning `r3`.
2. The most pretty-looking way is `_ctx.Employees.Skip(5).Take(5)`, because there is no query alternative to method calls of `Skip`, `Take`, `First`, etc.

Comment: As @Codesleuth said, `r3` looks like it may just select all and take the last record.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know what the last record is?  What determines the order?  Can't you make a call to OrderByDescending and then take the FirstOrDefault?  Perhaps that would yield a quicker query.