# Will my LinqToSql execution be deffered if i filter with IEnumerable<T> instead of IQueryable<T>?

Tags: linq-to-sql, extension-methods, ienumerable, expression-trees, iqueryable

I have been using these common EntityObjectFilters as a "pipes and filters" way to query from a collection a particular item with an ID:

```
public static class EntityObjectFilters
{
    public static T WithID<T>(this IQueryable<T> qry,
       int ID) where T : IEntityObject
    {
        return qry.SingleOrDefault<T>(item => item.ID == ID);
    }

    public static T WithID<T>(this IList<T> list,
        int ID) where T : IEntityObject
    {
        return list.SingleOrDefault<T>(item => item.ID == ID);
    }
}
```

..but i wondered to myself: "can i make this simpler by just creating an extension for all `IEnumerable<T>` types"?
So i came up with this:

```
public static class EntityObjectFilters
{
    public static T WithID<T>(this IEnumerable<T> qry,
       int ID) where T : IEntityObject
    {
        return qry.SingleOrDefault<T>(item => item.ID == ID);
    }
}
```

Now while this *appears* to yield the same result, i want to know that when applied to `IQueryable<T>`s will the expression tree be passed to LinqToSql for evaluating as SQL code **or** will my `qry` be evaluated in it's entirety first, then iterated with `Func`s?

I'm suspecting that (as per [Richard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433306/whats-the-difference-between-iqueryable-and-ienumerable/2433386#2433386)) the latter will be true which is obviously what i don't want. I want the same result, but the added benefit of the delayed SQL execution for `IQueryable<T>`s. Can someone confirm for me what will actually happen and provide simple explanation as to how it would work?

**EDIT:**

### Solution i went with

```
    public static T WithID<T>(this IEnumerable<T> qry,
        int ID) where T : DomainBase
    {
        if (qry is IQueryable<T>)
            return ((IQueryable<T>)qry).SingleOrDefault<T>(item => item.ID == ID);
        else
            return qry.SingleOrDefault<T>(item => item.ID == ID);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, when `qry` is typed as `IEnumerable<T>` it will call `Enumerable.SingleOrDefault` rather than `Queryable.SingleOrDefault`. The lambda expression will be converted into a delegate instead of an expression tree, and it won't use SQL.

Note that `SingleOrDefault` doesn't use deferred execution in the first place - it's always immediate - but the difference is where the querying is performed. You almost certainly want the database to do it. If you have a look at your logs with the simplified version, you'll see that *all* the results are being fetched - whereas with the `IQueryable<T>` overload the SQL will contain the relevant filtering.

Comment: Are you saying that in the first function in the first example the `SingleOrDefault` won't even use an SQL `WHERE`?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what Jon meens. Doing this will possibly retrieve all data rows from a table and filter client side. This would be very bad for performance.

Comment: Hold on: he says `SingleOrDefault` does not use deferred execution but it can query in SQL if it's `Queryable.SingleOrDefault`. This would seem to suggest that the first function in the first example the would use an SQL `WHERE`. Agreed?

Comment: @cottsak: The first function should use a WHERE in the SQL, yes. Using your second snippet, over `IEnumerable<T>` *won't* use a WHERE.

Comment: @Jon: refer to the edit: Is this an acceptable compromise meeting the requirements in a single extension method?

Comment: @cottsak: Yes - it's a bit ugly, but it makes it somewhat simpler for the caller. One issue is that you then *can't* easily force it to be done in-process; usually you'd consider using `AsEnumerable` to force the rest of a query to be performed in-process, but that won't work in this case.

Comment: Yeh it's not that attractive with the casting garb. 
I'm not sure the option of forcing the use of delegates is any advantage in the case of selecting a single item. I can understand the case for a range - good example is when the expression logic can't be converted to SQL. Why might the 'in-process' option be an advantage to me in this case?

Comment: @cottsak: I don't think it would, to be honest. It was more of a general concern when you start doing this sort of thing - it's something to watch out for if you do anything similar in the future.

Comment: @Jon I think i just found a bug. By extending `IEnumerable<T>` like i have in my solution example, am i not forcing `qry` to always be cast to `IEnumerable<T>` within the method? And by doing so (casting to a less derived type), never getting to the first part of the `if` condition?

Comment: @cottsak: No, because "is" deals with the *execution time* type of the object, not the *compile time* type.

Comment: @Jon: What is your view of pre-compilation (like this: http://lanitdev.wordpress.com/2010/01/06/unexpected-benefits-of-precompilation-of-linq/) in this case? I can't seem to tell if there is a benefit.

Comment: @cottsak: I don't have enough experience to say, to be honest.