# How to use IQueryable types in DataGridViewColumnCollection in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, extension-methods, iqueryable

I want to set DataGridView's columns to ReadOnly except one or two columns.

I was trying to do this.

```
dgv.Columns.AsQueryable().ForEach(col=>col.ReadOnly=true);
```

But I found that these extension methods are not available at DataGridViewColumnCollection

How can I do the same by this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original idea of LINQ is not to modify existing collections, but to return new ones, so methods like `ForEach` are not among the default LINQ methods.

You could easily write your own ForEach like:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
        action(item);
}
```

and so your code would become:

```
dgv.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>.ForEach(col=>col.ReadOnly=true);
```

**BTW...**
it is really worthwhile writing it as LINQ extension, when with 2 lines of old imperative-school code you can do the same ?

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in this.dataGridView1.Columns)
    col.ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: Completely agree with digEmAll! Here's the post (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/04/08/why-i-don-t-use-the-foreach-extension-method.aspx) that explains reason for absence of ForEach.

Comment: Thx for response with bringing very good knowledge for making me recognize my area of working with Extension Methods. I would take care of these points. But I am a learner in Linq so I would keep using it for few more months until I get complete knowledge about it. I never used IQueryable so I was trying to explore it.

Comment: OK, for IQueryable and IEnumerable differences see for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433306/whats-the-difference-between-iqueryable-and-ienumerable

Answer (score 1):

ForEach method isn't implemented neither in DataGridViewColumnCollection nor in IQueryable interface. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) is the post about it from Eric Lippert's blog. 

If you need this functionality you can easily implement extension method

```
public static void ForEach(this DataGridViewColumnCollection cols, Action<DataGridViewColumn> action)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in cols)
        {
            action(col);
        }
    }
```

And then use it:

```
dgv.Columns.ForEach(col => col.ReadOnly = true);
```

But, I think, it's much more easier just to iterate throw the columns.

```
foreach (var column in dgv.Columns)
   column.ReadOnly = true;
```