# does converting IQueryable to IEnumerable execute the query again?

Tags: c#, linq

In my query i need to return  `IEnumerable` but i dont know if this action make the query to execute again?

`var data = Repository<Person>.Find().AsEnumerable();`

`Find()` returns `IQueryable` and because `IQueryable` inherits `IEnumerable`. I doubt if `AsEnumerable` make the repetitive execution.

I know that
`var data = Repository<Person>.Find().ToList()` executes the query two times. One for `Find()` and second for `Tolist()`

Comment: See below: `Repository<Person>.Find()` erroneously contained `ToList()`. Without it, `Repository<Person>.Find().ToList()` executes the query only once.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

An `IQueryable` *is* an `IEnumerable`. There is no conversion, and therefore no work of any kind going on.

The work happens when you call `GetEnumerator()`, either explicitly or by invoking `foreach` on it.

Also, have you confirmed that `Repository.Find().ToList()` calls SQL twice? That doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: To make this more correct. IQueryable is not an IEnumerable... but it does inherit from it. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433306/whats-the-difference-between-iqueryable-and-ienumerable

Comment: @Jimmyt1988: There is nothing wrong with the argument *IQueryable is an IEnumerable*. If `A` inherits or implements `B` then we say `A` *is* `B`. Just like *Cat is an Animal*.

Answer (score 14):

`AsEnumerable` does not actually do anything except apply the `as` operator to your `IQueryable`. Accordingly, any future method you apply to your object will use the `System.Linq.Enumerable` set of extension methods as opposed to the `System.Linq.Queryable` methods.

It's all about deferred execution. Nothing ever gets executed against your queryable source (the database presumably) until you try to enumerate.

In other words:

```
var data=Repository.Find().AsEnumerable() 
/* The query is only actually performed AFTER here */  
.ToList();
```

If your code:

```
var data=Repository.Find().ToList();
```

executes the query two times, it's because you're doing something incorrect in your Find() method, which should definitely should not be the case.

```
var data = Respository.Find();
```

should execute the query ZERO times.

```
var result = data.ToList(); // THIS is what should execute the query.
```

Comment: u were right i had tolist() at the end of find method and i didnt notice that.sry

Comment: You mentioned about how IQueryable inherits from IEnumerable and therefore the AsEnumerable will not warrant any run to the database. However, you also mentioned about how the subsequent methods on the object will be those on IEnumerable isntead of IQueryable. In this sense, does it mean once I run the IEnumerable method, the query will execute, come back and be queried in memory? Or does the rule that "only be executed on database if GetEnumerator() is called" still hold?

Answer (score 2):

think of linq as a "Stream" and aggregate function is a "Flush". "linq to db" stream can only flush once.
.AsEnumerable(), .Where(), .... is a way to prepare query
.ToList(), .First(), .Max() is an aggregate
but if u not call aggregate, then your linq result wont run. its start to work only when its being enumerate.

ex

```
var result = users.Select(usr => usr.Name);
```

nothing will happen here until

1 aggregate is called

```
result.First()
```

or 2 result is being enumerate

```
result.ToList().ForEach(...)
```

to answer yout question - .Find(), .AsEnumerable() is not an aggregate function