# Whether to use AsEnumerable() in LINQ or not?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-5, linq-to-objects

I understand `AsEnumerable()` is used to switch from "LINQ to SQL" to "LINQ to Object", so we can use some extra (mostly user defined) methods in our LINQ queries. But from my experience I've seen, using `AsEnumerable()` makes the query much slower. In that case I can enumerate the list later to apply my own methods, but still the result is pretty slow.

Can anyone suggest any better approach?

Here is some code sample of what I'm trying to do?

*With AsEnumerable():*

```
var Data = (from r in _context.PRD_ChemProdReq.AsEnumerable()
                    //where r.RecordStatus == "NCF"
                    orderby r.RequisitionNo descending
                    select new PRDChemProdReq
                    {
                        RequisitionID = r.RequisitionID,
                        RequisitionNo = r.RequisitionNo,
                        RequisitionCategory = DalCommon.ReturnRequisitionCategory(r.RequisitionCategory),
                        RequisitionType = DalCommon.ReturnOrderType(r.RequisitionType),
                        ReqRaisedOn = (Convert.ToDateTime(r.ReqRaisedOn)).ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy"),
                        RecordStatus= DalCommon.ReturnRecordStatus(r.RecordStatus),
                        RequisitionFromName = DalCommon.GetStoreName(r.RequisitionFrom),
                        RequisitionToName = DalCommon.GetStoreName(r.RequisitionTo)
                    }).ToList();
```

without AsEnumerable():

```
var Data = (from r in _context.PRD_ChemProdReq
                    //where r.RecordStatus == "NCF"
                    orderby r.RequisitionNo descending
                    select new PRDChemProdReq
                    {
                        RequisitionID = r.RequisitionID,
                        RequisitionNo = r.RequisitionNo,
                        RequisitionCategory = r.RequisitionCategory,
                        RequisitionType = (r.RequisitionType),
                        ReqRaisedOnTemp = (r.ReqRaisedOn),
                        RecordStatus= (r.RecordStatus),
                        RequisitionFrom = (r.RequisitionFrom),
                        RequisitionTo = (r.RequisitionTo)
                    }).ToList();

        foreach (var item in Data)
        {
            item.RequisitionCategory = DalCommon.ReturnRequisitionCategory(item.RequisitionCategory);
            item.RequisitionType = DalCommon.ReturnOrderType(item.RequisitionType);
            item.ReqRaisedOn = (Convert.ToDateTime(item.ReqRaisedOnTemp)).ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy");
            item.RecordStatus = DalCommon.ReturnRecordStatus(item.RecordStatus);
            item.RequisitionFromName = DalCommon.GetStoreName(item.RequisitionFrom);
            item.RequisitionToName = DalCommon.GetStoreName(item.RequisitionTo);
        }
```

Comment: XY problem. Your real problem comes from you mixing your display logic with your data access logic.

Comment: Not much difference between the two code snippets, you are invariably bringing data in the memory, once by using the AsEnumerable, then ToList() and in other case using the ToList(). You can find the difference only when you use IEnumerable and IQueryable separately. IQueryable will help execution of query via data provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys, I took notice of different points from all of you & came up with this:

```
var Data = (from r in _context.PRD_ChemProdReq.AsEnumerable()
                    //where r.RecordStatus == "NCF"

                    join rf in _context.SYS_Store on (r.RequisitionFrom==null?0: r.RequisitionFrom) equals rf.StoreID into requisitionfrom
                    from rf in requisitionfrom.DefaultIfEmpty()

                    join rt in _context.SYS_Store on (r.RequisitionTo == null ? 0 : r.RequisitionTo) equals rt.StoreID into requisitionto
                    from rt in requisitionto.DefaultIfEmpty()

                    orderby r.RequisitionNo descending
                    select new PRDChemProdReq
                    {
                        RequisitionID = r.RequisitionID,
                        RequisitionNo = r.RequisitionNo,
                        RequisitionCategory = DalCommon.ReturnRequisitionCategory(r.RequisitionCategory),
                        RequisitionType = r.RequisitionType == "UR" ? "Urgent" : "Normal",
                        ReqRaisedOn = (Convert.ToDateTime(r.ReqRaisedOn)).ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy"),
                        RecordStatus = (r.RecordStatus=="NCF"? "Not Confirmed": "Approved"),
                        RequisitionFromName = (rf==null? null: rf.StoreName),
                        RequisitionToName = (rt == null ? null : rt.StoreName)
                    });
```

First of all I removed my ToList() which does nothing but executes the query which is already done when I called AsEnumerable(). No points to execute the same query twice. Also my custom method calls within the select block was also playing a major part slowing down things. I tried lessen the method calls, rather used join where possible. It makes things pretty faster. Thank You all.

Comment: You are still mixing DAO with Display logic. ALL of your code in select should be in you UI! This is really bad software design.

Comment: @Jain, you need to ask yourself a question - do I worry about loading some crazy amount of records every time I run this query? If yes, this approach won't solve your problem anyway. If you don't worry about it, then you can go with `.AsEnumerable`.

Comment: @Aron I know. But the project is already developed in this fashion, so I have very few choices. But definitely we will try to make things better while updating in future.

Comment: @Alexey You are right. We will have to implement server paging at some point, for the time being I'm going with .AsEnumerable.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you confuse these two interfaces as two totally different things. In fact `IQueryable` is inherited from `IEnumerable`, so whatever worked for you using with latter, would work with former as well, so don't need to use `AsEnumerable`.

Behind the scenes though these interfaces are implemented quite differently - IEnumerable will process your  collection in memory, and IQueryable would pass the query to the underlying data provider. You can imagine that if a database table contains millions of records and you try to sort it, DB server can do it very quickly (using indexes) so Queryable will shine.  For IEnumerable, all the data need to be loaded to your  computer memory and sorted there.

For a longer answers search for **"IEnumerable IQueryable difference"** on SO, you will see a plenty of details:

[Random Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet)
[Random Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433306/whats-the-difference-between-iqueryable-and-ienumerable?rq=1)

**Update:** If you remove call `.ToList` from your second example, then the result won't be automatically loaded to memory. At this point you need to decide which items you want to store in memory and call your functions for them only.

```
var Data = (from r in _context.PRD_ChemProdReq
           orderby r.RequisitionNo descending
           select new PRDChemProdReq
           {
               // do your initialization
           });

var subsetOfData = Data.Take(100).ToList(); // Now it's loaded to memory
foreach (var item in subsetOfData)
{
    item.RequisitionCategory = DalCommon.ReturnRequisitionCategory(item.RequisitionCategory);
    item.RequisitionType = DalCommon.ReturnOrderType(item.RequisitionType);
    item.ReqRaisedOn = (Convert.ToDateTime(item.ReqRaisedOnTemp)).ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy");
    item.RecordStatus = DalCommon.ReturnRecordStatus(item.RecordStatus);
    item.RequisitionFromName = DalCommon.GetStoreName(item.RequisitionFrom);
    item.RequisitionToName = DalCommon.GetStoreName(item.RequisitionTo);
}
```

Now if you actually need to assign these properties for **all** your data and data can be arbitrary large, you need to work out a strategy how you can do it. The very simple option is to save them to database to  a new table, then the size of processed data will be only limited by the capacity of your database.

Comment: I can understand your points, but what should be the right way to make things faster in my case, if I don't use AsEnumerable(), I can't use user defined method call within select block, so I have to enumerate later and if I use AsEnumerable(), the whole records comes into memory, which is not good too.

Comment: @Jain The technique that is used normally is that you do a `select` of the fields you need, and then in a `foreach` you "format" them. That is what you are doing in the second example.

Comment: @xanatos So, you are saying that is better than using .AsEnumerable(), right? I will try to follow it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`AsEnumerable()` will be slower if you add any query elements after it.

Even though `AsEnumerable()` doesn't execute the query directly, applying a `where` or `orderby` **after** the `AsEnumerable()` means that the Sql will get **all** items and then apply *filtering* and *ordering* to the collection in memory.

In short:

- Without `AsEnumerable()` = filtering and ordering done in SQL
- With `AsEnumerable()` and then `Where` or `orderby` = applied to whole collection brought into memory.

You can only run user defined functions on a collection in memory (as your Linq to SQL will not be able to interpret your functions to SQL code). So your second code snippet (without `AsEnumerable()`) is probably best.

The only other alternative is to apply your *user defined functions* in SQL itself.

Comment: AsEnumerable() brings all the record in memory and then apply the filters, that's why we can use user defined function in select block, without using AsEnumerable(), using any user defined method call within the select block will throw an error.

Comment: @Jain, you're absolutely right, my apologies, `AsEnumerable()` doesn't execute the query bringing the result set to memory, however any further statements or filter applied will be done to the result set in memory. I've updated the answer accordingly.