# Entity Framework bulk insert with updating rows from another table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, insert, bulkinsert

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server and Entity Framework. I have N (for example 10 000) items to insert. Before inserting each item I need to insert or update existing group. It doesn't work well because of low performance. It's because I'm generating too many queries. Each time in loop I'm looking for group by querying `Groups` table by three (already indexed) parameters.

I was thinking about querying first all groups by using `WHERE IN` query (`Groups.Where(g => owners.Contains(g.OwnerId) && ..` ), but as I remember such queries are limited by number of parameters.

Maybe I should write a stored procedure?

Here is my example code. I'm using `IUnitOfWork` pattern for wrapping the EF `DbContext`:

```
public async Task InsertAsync(IItem item)
{
    var existingGroup = await this.unitOfWork.Groups.GetByAsync(item.OwnerId, item.Type, item.TypeId);

    if (existingGroup == null)
    {
        existingGroup = this.unitOfWork.Groups.CreateNew();
        existingGroup.State = GroupState.New;
        existingGroup.Type = item.Code;
        existingGroup.TypeId = item.TypeId;
        existingGroup.OwnerId = item.OwnerId;
        existingGroup.UpdatedAt = item.CreatedAt;

        this.unitOfWork.Groups.Insert(existingGroup);
    }
    else
    {
        existingGroup.UpdatedAt = item.CreatedAt;
        existingGroup.State = GroupState.New;

        this.unitOfWork.Groups.Update(existingGroup);
    }

    this.unitOfWork.Items.Insert(item);
}

foreach(var item in items)
{
    InsertAsync(item);
}

await this.unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three key elements to improve performance when bulk inserting:

- Set `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` and `ValidateOnSaveEnabled` to false:

`_db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;`
`_db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;`

- Break up your inserts into segments, wich use the same `DbContext`, then recreate it. How large the segment should be varies from use-case to use-case, I made best performance at around 100 Elements before recreating the Context. This is due to the observing of the elements in the DbContext.
  Also make sure not to recreate the context for every insert. 
  (See [Slauma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270591/slauma)'s answer here [Fastest Way of Inserting in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework))
- When checking other tables, make sure to use `IQueryable` where possible and to work only where necessary with `ToList()` or `FirstOrDefault()`. Since `ToList()` and `FirstOrDefault()` loads the objects. (See [Richard Szalay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3603/richard-szalay)'s answer here [What's the difference between IQueryable and IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433306/whats-the-difference-between-iqueryable-and-ienumerable))

These tricks helped me out the most when bulk inserting in a scenario as you described. There are also other possibilities. For example SP's, and the BulkInsert function.

Comment: I've used your suggestion with disabling AutoDetectChanges for few queries. Unfortunately EF generates too many heavy queries and I've also rewritten few EF queries to raw SQL queries and stored procedures. Works fine now.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Well in some cases it's probably best to do so. Sometimes EF just overcomplicates things, but we have to pay attention that we don't do that ourself.