# Difference between IQueryable, ICollection, IList & IDictionary interface

Tags: c#, .net, performance, list, collections

I am trying to understand difference between IQueryable, ICollection, IList & IDictionary interface
which is more faster for basic operations like iterating, Indexing, Querying and more.

which class like Collection, List, Dictionary etc would be good to initiating with these interfaces and when should we be using these class. Basic advantages of using these classes over others.

I tried reading other posts with similar questions but nothing answered my full questions.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

All of these interfaces inherit from **[`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable)**, which you should make sure you understand. That interface basically lets you use the class in a `foreach` statement (in C#).

- **[`ICollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icollection)** is the most basic of the interfaces you listed. It's an enumerable interface that supports a Count and that's about it.
- **[`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist)** is everything that `ICollection` is, but it also supports adding and removing items, retrieving items by index, etc. It's the most commonly-used interface for "lists of objects", which is vague I know.
- **[`IQueryable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable)** is an enumerable interface that supports LINQ. You can always create an `IQueryable` from an `IList` and use LINQ to Objects, but you also find `IQueryable` used for deferred execution of SQL statements in LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities.
- **[`IDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary)** is a different animal in the sense that it is a mapping of unique keys to values. It is also enumerable in that you can enumerate the key/value pairs, but otherwise it serves a different purpose than the others you listed.

The MSDN documentation for each of these is decent, so I would start there in rounding out your understanding.

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation for these Interface but you are missing my other questions

Comment: In terms of the generic versions of the interfaces, ICollection<T> supports Add/Remove/Clear/Contains/CopyTo as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx

Answer (score 11):

I noticed few issues in [gunny229's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29209513/465053). I've mentioned those issues in comment area of his post. Later on, I thought to write a more detailed post to connect some missing dots.

**Disclaimer**: I don't intend to cater OP's question in entirety but I want to point out the difference between **IQueryable** and **IEnumerable** when using LINQ to SQL.

I created following structure in DB (DDL script):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee]([PersonId] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,[Salary] [int] NOT NULL)
```

Here is the record insertion script (DML script):

```
INSERT INTO [EfTest].[dbo].[Employee] ([PersonId],[Salary])VALUES(1, 20)
INSERT INTO [EfTest].[dbo].[Employee] ([PersonId],[Salary])VALUES(2, 30)
INSERT INTO [EfTest].[dbo].[Employee] ([PersonId],[Salary])VALUES(3, 40)
INSERT INTO [EfTest].[dbo].[Employee] ([PersonId],[Salary])VALUES(4, 50)
INSERT INTO [EfTest].[dbo].[Employee] ([PersonId],[Salary])VALUES(5, 60)
GO
```

Now my goal was to get top 2 records from **Employee** table in database. I created a new C# console application in Visual Studio (VS). Then, I added an ADO.NET Entity Data Model XML (EDMX) item pointing to **Employee** table in the database. Now I can start writing LINQ queries.

**Case I:** Code for **IQueryable** route

```
using (var efContext = new EfTestEntities())
{
    IQueryable<int> employees = from e in efContext.Employees  select e.Salary;
    employees = employees.Take(2);

    foreach (var item in employees)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Before running this program, I had started a session of SQL Query profiler on the SQL Server instance. Here is the summary of execution:

1. Total number of queries fired: **1**
2. Query text:

   ```
   SELECT TOP (2) [c].[Salary] AS [Salary] FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [c]
   ```

We can see that **IQueryable** is smart enough to apply the `Top (2)` clause on database server side itself. So it brings only 2 out of 5 records over the network. No more in-memory filtering is required on the client side.

**Case II:** Code for **IEnumerable** route

```
using (var efContext = new EfTestEntities())
{
    IEnumerable<int> employees = from e in efContext.Employees  select e.Salary;
    employees = employees.Take(2);

    foreach (var item in employees)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Summary of execution in this case:

1. Total number of queries fired: **1**
2. Query text captured in SQL profiler:

   ```
   SELECT [Extent1].[Salary] AS [Salary] FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Extent1]
   ```

Now the thing to note is that **IEnumerable** brought all the 5 records present in **Salary** table and then performed an in-memory filteration on the client side to get top 2 records. So more data (3 additional records in this case) got transferred over the network and ate up the bandwidth unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think @gunny229 's answer is anyway misleading. Yes he used the word 'query' but that's not in the context of a database. It's just another computation to get the top two. At least that's what I figured when reading it. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

IQueryable,IList,IDictionary,ICollection inherits IEnumerable Interface.
All the interfaces of type collection will inherits IEnumerable Interface.

***Differences Between IEnumerable and IQueryable***
**IEnumerable**: Wen you are running a query which returns of type  IEnumerable.
IEnumerable will first Executes the first query and then executes the sub queries written for that query.

**Example**: If you want get the top 10 population Records from a Particular country then the query we will use in LINQ is

```
IEnumerable<LongInt> _Population=from s in India select s.population;//First Query
_Population=_Population.take(10);//Second Query
```

Now if we execute this query First Query will be executed first the IEnumerable will get the Records of all the population from the sql server then it will store the data in the In Process memory and then it executes the top 10 population  in the next Query.(Execution is taken place for two times on sql server).

If we execute the same query by using IQueryable .

```
IQueryable<LongInt>  _Population=from s in India select s.population;//First Query
_Population=_Population.take(10);//Second Query
```

in this IQueryable it will execute the two Queries at the same time in the sense it will get the population which is of top 10 in a single Query instead of getting the data and filtering the first 10 again.(One time execution on sql server).

**Conclusion for IQueryable and IEnumerable**

1. If you are writing the query against the data in the database then
   use IQueryable.
2. If you are querying against the in process data then
   use IEnumerable.
   IEnumerable has a methods GetEnumerator(),Current() and MoveNext().

Comment: Really nice to know the difference. (y)

Comment: extension method `Take` is defined on `IEnumerable<T>` instead. I verified that *only 1* query gets fired in both the cases be it `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`. It is just that `IEnumerable` does in-memory filtering which brings undesired data over the wire.