# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<TMS.Models.CustomAsset>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following model class :-

```
public class CustomerCustomAssetJoin
{
    public CustomAsset CustomAsset  { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CustomAsset> CustomAssets { get; set; }

}
```

But when i wrote the following method:-

```
public CustomerCustomAssetJoin CustomerCustomAsset(string customerName)
{
    var customerAssets = tms.CustomAssets.Include(a => a.CustomAssetType).Where(a => a.CustomerName.ToLower() == customerName.ToLower());
    CustomerCustomAssetJoin caj = new CustomerCustomAssetJoin
    {
         CustomAsset = new CustomAsset {CustomerName = customerName },
         CustomAssets = customerAssets
    };
    return caj;  
 }
```

I got the following exception :

> Error 20  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

So what is causing this error? To overcome this error i just add a .toList() as follows:

```
var customerAssets = tms.CustomAssets.Include(a => a.CustomAssetType).Where(a => a.CustomerName.ToLower() == customerName.ToLower());
```

So why do I have to convert it to a list?

Comment: ICollection and IQueryable are different things. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455428/difference-between-iqueryable-icollection-ilist-idictionary-interface

Answer (score 7):

What you have stored in the `customerAssets` is just a query - a way, how to get the data. It's not the data itself yet, because it's lazily evaluated. `ICollection<T>` is an interface built for manipulating data collections that you already have. The query does not implement it, so you cannot implicitly convert from `IQueryable<T>` to the `ICollection<T>` Calling `ToList()` is a simple way how to force loading the data into an `ICollection<T>`, but it also means in your case, that at that place in code (and execution time) the query will get executed and data will be loaded from whatever database you are querying.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you defined your `CustomAssets` as `ICollection<CustomAsset>`, while an `IQueryable<T>` does not implement any `ICollection<T>`. You need a result implementing `ICollection<CustomAsset>`, when you apply `ToList()`, it will convert to a `List<CustomAsset>` which in fact implements `ICollection<CustomAsset>`

Comment: @JohnJohn yes, unless you redefine your `CustomAssets` to `IQueryable<CustomAsset>`, using `ToList()` of course will run the query right and get the items for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the LINQ `Include` method returns an object of type `ObjectQuery(T)` which implements the `IQueryable<T>` interface whereas your class is expecting an object which implements the `ICollection<T>` interface. As both these objects cannot be implicitly converted from one to the other you have to explicitly convert the result of the `Include` method to a `List` type, which does implement the `ICollection<T>` interface.