# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, code-first, ef-code-first, entity-framework-ctp5

I am following [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff714955.aspx) on MSDN. I ported it to EF Code First.

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IRepository<Employee> Employees { get; }
    IRepository<TimeCard> TimeCards { get; }
    void Commit();
}
```

---

```
public class HrContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TimeCard> TimeCards { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                    .HasMany(e => e.TimeCards)
                    .WithOptional(tc => tc.Employee);
     }
}
```

---

```
public class SqlRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : class
{
    private readonly DbSet<T> entitySet;
    public SqlRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        this.entitySet = context.Set<T>();
    }
    public void Add(T newEntity)
    {
        this.entitySet.Add(newEntity);
    }
    public IQueryable<T> FindAll()
    {
        return this.entitySet;
    }
    public T FindById(params object[] keys)
    {
        return this.entitySet.Find(keys);
    }
    public IQueryable<T> FindWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return this.entitySet.Where(predicate);
    }
    public void Remove(T entity)
    {
        this.entitySet.Remove(entity);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class SqlUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private readonly HrContext context;
    private IRepository<Employee> employees;
    private IRepository<TimeCard> timeCards;
    public SqlUnitOfWork()
    {
        this.context = new HrContext();
    }
    public IRepository<Employee> Employees
    {
        get
        {
            return new SqlRepository<Employee>(context);
        }
    }
    public IRepository<TimeCard> TimeCards
    {
        get
        {
            return new SqlRepository<TimeCard>(context);
        }
    }
    public void Commit()
    {
        this.context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

---

```
var query = from e in unitOfWork.Employees.FindAll()
            from tc in unitOfWork.TimeCards.FindAll()
            where tc.Employee.Id == e.Id && e.Name.StartsWith("C")
            select tc;
var timeCards = query.ToList();
```

This model is great as it gives me testability. However, running queries like the one above throws this

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[DomainModel.Models.TimeCard] FindAll()' 
  method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I understand the error but is there any way to avoid it but still keep the repositories for testability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your select statement cannot be translated due to the nature of how `IQueryable<T>` and the query providers work: see this thread for more info [What is the difference between IQueryable<T> and IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet)

You can 'help' the linq provider by dividing your expression into separate statements like this:

```
var ems = unitOfWork.Employees.FindAll();
var tcs = unitOfWork.TimeCards.FindAll();

var query = from e in ems
            from tc in tcs
            where tc.Employee.Id == e.Id && e.Name.StartsWith("C")
            select tc;
```

Or you can let FindAll() return `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IQueryable<T>` and then your original expression should work.

Comment: thanks it works. IEnumerable is greedy though. it brings everything in memory and does the join afterwards.