# IEnumerable<T> and IQueryable<T> clarification?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, iqueryable

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet) question, 
I need to clear up some things.

```
IQueryable<Customer> custs = from c in db.Customers
where c.City == "<City>"
select c;

IEnumerable<Customer> custs = from c in db.Customers
where c.City == "<City>"
select c;
```

Questions:

1) Is it ok to say that: in the first query  the SQLServer is running the whole operation including where clause and returning **ONLY** the relevant rows  - while the second one does `SELECT *` ... and returns  **all**  rows into C# and *THEN* filters ?

2) What about if I have a *collection* merely - in memory. ( `var lstMyPerson = new List<MyPerson>()` )

```
IQueryable<MyPerson> lst = from c in lstMyPerson 
where c.City == "<City>"
select c;
```

vs

```
IEnumerable<MyPerson> custs = from c in lstMyPerson 
where c.City == "<City>"
select c;
```

what will be the difference in execution now?

Comment: Take a look at this relevant topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet. And also, you are correct in your assumption in #1. Not 100% sure about #2 so I'll leave it to another.

Comment: @blizz i already read that. all answers there are from a book POV. nothing answering my  question there.... :(... ill be **happy** to see which line answeres my question

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**1: No, that is incorrect**

Since you're only *storing* the result into an `IEnumerable<Customer>`, but still have the exact same expression that produces the result, they will both execute on the server and return only the relevant rows.

You would get the difference in behavior with this:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> custs = from c in (IEnumerable<Customer>)db.Customers
    where c. City == "<City>"
    select c;
```

In this case you are forcing the `db.Customers` collection to be used as `IEnumerable<T>`, which when enumerated will fetch the entire collection.

Note that this:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> x = from c in db.Customers
                          where c.City == "<City>"
                          select c;
```

is not the same as this:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> x = from c in db.Customers
                          select c;
IEnumerable<Customer> y = x.Where(c => c.City == "<City>");
```

In the first case, the `where` clause will be a part of the SQL, in the second it won't. That is why the linked question/answer involves a difference, whereas your code does not.

Also note that *only* the statements you have written will not in fact execute anything at all on the server, since they will effectively only store a lazy collection. If you go ahead and enumerate those collections, *at that point* the relevant bits will be executed on the server.

**2: `List<T>` does not implement or have extension methods for `IQueryable<T>`, nor will the LINQ operators involved return anything compatible with `IQueryable<T>`**

In this case, the first will not compile.

Comment: No, as I said, they will both do the same. However, in the case of the linked code, the `Where` LINQ operator is applied to the `IEnumerable<T>` or the `IQueryable<T>`, you have added a `where` clause to the original query. This changes the order of the operations, so in your case, they will execute the same way. In the linked answer, they will not.

Comment: regarding  _forcing the db.Customers collection to be used as IEnumerable<T>, which when enumerated will fetch the entire collection_ , if i understood correctly , this code will get ALL CUSTOMERS and THEN Filter ?

Comment: Correct, that's what's going to happen.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Hi. (after a while...) in your `3'rd` code sample : the first line doesnt actually fetch the data from db. sow why the next line can't just add the `where` clause ? ( so when enumerating the whole query will be sent to db) ? is this kind of behavior is because the first line uses `Ienumerable` or because the second line uses `Ienumerable` or because the `x.where`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The reason is that the compiler no longer knows that the collection is one that can be queried. Meaning that since the collection has been stored into `IEnumerable<Customer>`, the `IQueryable<T>` operators are no longer available. As such, the last assignment in the answer will generate another lazy collection, but this collection will, when enumerated over, first fetch every customer from the database, and then filter in memory.