# Diferences between IEnumerable<TSource> Where & IQueryable<TSource> Where extension methods

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, extension-methods

What's the diference between

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>
        (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
```

and

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>
        (this IQueryable<TSource> source, 
         Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
```

Both methods can accept a lambda expression in the same way.

```
List<string> fruits =
                new List<string> { "apple", "passionfruit", "banana", "mango", 
                                "orange", "blueberry", "grape", "strawberry" };
IEnumerable<string> query = fruits.Where(fruit => fruit.Length < 6);
```

Why delegate function and expresion of delegate function exists? Must I take care about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `IEnumerable` is just a sequence of C# items. The `IEnumerable` version of `Select` literally just iterates, in C#, through the items in the input `IEnumerable`, tests them against the delegate function, and yields those that match.

An `IQueryable`, however, can represent e.g. items in a SQL table. (Or many other kinds of data source, but SQL may be the most common.) The `IQueryable` version of `Select` can convert the expression to part of an SQL query (or similar), and passes the burden of deciding which items to return back to the SQL server (or similar).

You don't really have to *worry* about this distinction - LINQ can hide all these details away for you. If you're querying a list of C# objects, it'll use the `IEnumerable` version; if you're querying SQL via Linq-to-SQL, it'll use the `IQueryable` version.

Answer (score 4):

One works on `IEnumerable<T>`, the other one works on `IQueryable<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

When you have an `IQueryable<T>` a eventually used datasource (SqlServer or something other) is not already queried and the generated sql could still be modified by additional conditions.

When you habe an `IEnumerable<T>` the possible query is materialized and you will only filter the collection.

Answer (score 2):

O.R. Mapper's answer is most adequate and simple. I think what you need to check is what's the [difference between IEnumerable and IQueryable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet) which you can find out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet).