# What is going on when intellisense the same extension method twice but defined on different types?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, extension-methods, intellisense

When using an EF `ObjectContext` I see two different extensions methods with the same signature as consecutive choices.  It doesn't makes sense to me that there would be some magic that caused one or the other to get called based on which one I picked, so what is actually going on?

[image]

Comment: One of them returns an `IQueryable`, the other returns an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: but they both return a `Campaign`, don't they?  I could be totally missing something in which case I apologize up front...

Comment: Right, they both return a Campaign. One is an extension method for an IQueryable<Campaign> and the other is an extension method for IEnumerable<Campaign>.

Comment: its not the end of the world if the answer to a question is clarifying the underlying confusion that caused it to be asked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that `Campaigns` is an instance of `DbSet<Campaign>`? `DbSet` inherits `DbQuery`, which implements `IOrderedQueryable`, the [definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340178.aspx) for which is:

```
public interface IOrderedQueryable<out T> : IQueryable<T>, 
    IEnumerable<T>, IOrderedQueryable, IQueryable, IEnumerable
```

As you can see, both `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` are implemented, but the definition of `IQueryable` shows that it extends `IEnumerable`:

`public interface IQueryable : IEnumerable`

So basically, the extension method is implemented for `IEnumerable`, but it's also available from `IQueryable` as it extends the original interface. Intellisense is picking up both of these options because you could end up implicitly or explicitly casting the type to an `IEnumerable`.

The method that will actually be run will depend on the type on which it's called. For example, on your `Campaigns` instance of `DbSet<Campaign>` the method will translate it (if you're using MS SQL) into a `SELECT TOP 1...` query, but if you're calling it on `Campaigns.ToList()`, which is `IEnumerable`, it'll return the item at the zero index. The implementation of the extension methods are different for each type.

Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: yes, that makes sense, thank you (it's ObjectSet but I bet your answer is right nonetheless)

Comment: Ah ok, `ObjectSet` implements `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` directly, so it's pretty much the same, just ignore the first paragraph and `IOrderedQueryable` definition. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412719.aspx

Comment: This also might be a useful read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet