# IQueryable select all?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, linq

I have this method, it selects data in a particular range (pageIndex and pageSize)

```
public PagedList(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {            
        this.AddRange(source.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList());
    }
```

I want to create an overloading method which selects all data, so, here's my code

```
public PagedList(IQueryable<T> source)
    {
       //this.AddRange(source.Select(x => new T()).ToList()); (1)
        this.AddRange(source.AsQueryable().ToList()); (2)
    }
```

Firstly, I tried (1), but it didn't accept T. Then I tried (2), and it's recommended that I should make parameter type INumerable instead of IQueryable. What is the solution to select all data in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it simply like this:

```
public PagedList(IEnumerable<T> source) 
{ 
    this.AddRange(source);
}
```

- `IEnumerable<T>` as parameter type instead of `IQueryable<T>`, because you don't use any features specific to `IQueryable<T>`.
- No `AsQueryable` because you simply want all data
- No `ToList` as `List<T>.AddRange` internally already performs a copy. With `ToList` there would be two copy operations going on.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it helps.
For the record, I tried something like 
this.AddRange(source.Select( x => new Dokument {
Beschreibung = x.Beschreibung, Dokumenttyp = x.Dokumenttyp.Bezeichnung}).ToList()); 
But it didn't recognize Dokument. Anyway, just keep it simple like your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What would be wrong with:

```
public PagedList(IQueryable<T> source)
{
    this.AddRange(source.ToList());
}
```

Making something Queryable just to then make it a list seems weird. Especially given that source is already Queryable.

Answer (score 0):

Both IEnumerable and IQueryable are fine, it depends only on what you actualy need.

For a better case sudy you can read this.

[What is the difference between IQueryable<T> and IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet)