# AsEnumerable().Take

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, linq-to-dataset

I want to take fist n number of records from a data table.

I don't want to run a loop which I already know.

I'm trying to do this

```
DataTable dt = dtResult.AsEnumerable().Take(n)
```

is the right way..?

what is the process to make this "n records" to be in another datatable..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is a correct way to take first N rows from your data table. Use [CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx) extension to create new data table from query result:

```
DataTable dt = dtResult.AsEnumerable()
                       .Take(n)
                       .CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 2):

lazyberezovsky's answer is correct, however perhaps you'd like to use `AsQueryable` rather than `AsEnumerable` if you would like to do some more fancy things than just `Take` as the `IQueryable` interface gives you more freedom to write expressions against collections that you haven't got in memory yet. I'd say `IQueryable` is more suitable for interaction with a database than `IEnumerable` is. More info: [What is the difference between IQueryable and IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet)

```
DataTable dt = dtResult.AsQueryable()
                       .Take(n)
                       .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Looks like he is querying DataTable, not database

Answer (score 0):

Try this `.CopyToDataTable()`. E.g.

```
DataTable dt = dtResult.AsEnumerable().Take(5).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: `new DataTable()` will create.. new DataTable

Comment: copy and paste syndrome - my bad :)