# How to insert if in where condition SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, where-clause

I have this query,

```
SELECT [Equipment]
      ,[CounterType]      
      ,SUM([Quantity])
FROM [FlexNet].[dbo].[AT_MACHINE_COUNTER]
WHERE 
    CreatedOn IS NOT NULL
    AND [FlexNet].[dbo].AF_GetUTCToLocal(CreatedOn) between @DATA_START and @DATA_END
    AND [Equipment] LIKE @MACHINE
    AND CounterType IN 
    (CASE WHEN @MACHINE LIKE 'PACKER001' THEN 2 END)
```

I would like to insert this IF in WHERE condition:

```
IF @MACHINE LIKE 'PACKER001' THEN CounterType = 1
ELSE 'I don't want apply any condition'
```

So the query should be similar this (but I know that this query not found):

```
    SELECT [Equipment]
          ,[CounterType]      
          ,SUM([Quantity])
    FROM [FlexNet].[dbo].[AT_MACHINE_COUNTER]
    WHERE 
        CreatedOn IS NOT NULL
        AND [FlexNet].[dbo].AF_GetUTCToLocal(CreatedOn) between @DATA_START and @DATA_END
        AND [Equipment] LIKE @MACHINE
                    IF @MACHINE LIKE 'PACKER001' THEN 
                       AND CounterType =2
                    END IF
```

Can we help me?
reguars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there in your first attempt. Just add `Else` part in your `Case Statement` with `CounterType` problem solved .

```
SELECT [Equipment],
       [CounterType],
       Sum([Quantity])
FROM   [FlexNet].[dbo].[AT_MACHINE_COUNTER]
WHERE  CreatedOn IS NOT NULL
       AND [FlexNet].[dbo].Af_getutctolocal(CreatedOn) BETWEEN @DATA_START AND @DATA_END
       AND [Equipment] LIKE @MACHINE
       AND CounterType = CASE
                           WHEN @MACHINE LIKE 'PACKER001' THEN 2
                           ELSE CounterType
                         END
```

Answer (score 3):

You can build up conditional where clauses by combining both 'branches' with an `OR` clause like this example, although note that this is fraught with performance and maintainability challenges:

```
SELECT [Equipment]
      ,[CounterType]      
      ,SUM([Quantity])
FROM [FlexNet].[dbo].[AT_MACHINE_COUNTER]
WHERE 
    CreatedOn IS NOT NULL
    AND [FlexNet].[dbo].AF_GetUTCToLocal(CreatedOn) between @DATA_START and @DATA_END
    AND [Equipment] LIKE @MACHINE
    AND (@MACHINE = 'PACKER001' AND CounterType IN (2)
         OR @MACHINE <> 'PACKER001')
```

As an alternative to doing this in Sql, I would typically try to manage this kind of dynamic filtering on data in the application layer, e.g. LINQ features such as using `IQueryable` to conditionally compose filters, or the excellent [`PredicateBuilder`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet) do this much easier.