# Using query expression vs Seq modules?

Tags: linq, f#, fsharp.data.sqlclient

Are there any advantages in using the query expression over Sequence modules when manipulating data retrieved via FSharp.Data.SqlClient?

For example:

```
query{
    for row in SelectAllCategories.Execute() do
    where row.Id = 1
    select {
        Id = row.Id;
        Category = row.CategoryName
    }
}
```

versus

```
SelectAllCategories.Execute()
|> Seq.filter (fun x -> x.Id = 1)
|> Seq.map (fun x ->
                {
                   Id = x.Id;
                   Category = x.CategoryName
                }
```

For that matter you can even consider LINQ as well.  So what are the advantages if any, specifically in regards to FSharp.Data.SqlClient?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/252789/1612190

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this particular case `FSharp.Data.SqlClient` provides the default `IEnumerable<ProvidedType>.Record` result type, not `IQueryable<ProvidedType>` of any sort. All communications with SQL engine are opaque to query expression, being encapsulated into provided `SqlCommandProvider.Execute()` method. So any potential benefits of `query {...}` using Linq-to-Sql are not in play here.

Hence, I'd not be surprised that the case with functions from `Seq` module would yield better performance having less overhead, than underlying desugared machinery associated with query expressions. No advantages of using the query expression here.

Answer (score 2):

Query builder provides a way to construct `IQueryables` in F#, `Seq` module functions work on `IEnumerables` (that `seq` type is an alias for). Those are general .NET interfaces rather than an F# thing, and the differences between them are well outlined for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet).

Also, apart from `Seq` module functions you also have the `seq` builder:

```
seq {
   for row in SelectAllCategories.Execute() do 
       if row.Id = 1 then 
           yield { Id = row.Id; Category = row.CategoryName }
}
```

It's roughly equivalent to using `Seq` module functions, so the choice of one over the other is mostly a style or convenience decision.

Comment: I should have clarified my question. My understanding is that FSharp.Data.SqlClient returns a sequence when called, so is there any point or benefit to using the query expression syntax with it?

Comment: I would say no, there's no point in using `IQueryable` when there's nothing to interpret the query. So this would be my understanding as well. I'm not an expert on `FSharp.Data.SqlClient` though.