# Filter data from a virtual foreign key on an SQL query

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am relatively new to Lambda/Linq, however I want to retrieve all events from a specific calendar where the events are still in the future...

If I use:

```
EventCalendar eventCalendar;
eventCalendar = db.Events_Calendars.Find(id);
```

I can get all events and filter by the current date in the view, but I don't think that is the best method.

The Model is as follows:

```
[Table("Events_Calendars")]
public class EventCalendar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Calendar { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

Event Model is:

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public int? Capacity { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

One of my failed attempts at this issue is:

```
eventCalendar = db.Events_Calendars.Where(x => x.Events.Any(y => y.End >= DateTime.Today));
```

But it is giving me "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<...Models.EventCalendar>' to '...Models.EventCalendar'

EDIT: Added the declaration line... EventCalendar eventCalendar;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Events_Calendars.Where` returns the `IQueryable<Models.EventCalendar>` that means a some "query source" of `Models.EventCalendar` items but `Events_Calendars.Find` return the one `Models.EventCalendar`, so you cannot convert a some set of `Models.EventCalendar` to `Models.EventCalendar`. You can declarate the new varibale `eventCalendars` and store the filtering items to it:

```
var eventCalendars = db.Events_Calendars.Where(x => x.Events.Any(y => y.End >= DateTime.Today)).ToList();
```

Also you can [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet) about difference between `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable`

Comment: Your explanation and example got me past that issue with a better understanding (thanks to the extra read), 

I still need to limit it by a specific calendar and only list future events.  I am struggling with understanding how to filter the virtual Event(s) since it is essentially pulling data from a second table.

Comment: Update: I fixed the single calendar issue by adding "&& x.Id == id" to the where clause, but the filter by future date still doesn't work.

Comment: @thefid Put info about a new error or exception into the current question if you have it. Are you sure that `db.Events_Calendars` isn't empty and that you need to compare `y.End >= DateTime.Today` but `y.Start >= DateTime.Today`?

Comment: The way I have my example query above, it will only return the calendar IF there are future events with that calendar Id and it will return all events regardless of future or past. There is no error. My problem is related to eager loading and wanting to filter that data efficiently in the controller (not the view). I need to move the filter out of the where clause as in our examples above.

Comment: `My problem is related to eager loading and wanting to filter that data efficiently` I think that it's a another question how to improve performance of data filtering, where you should post additionally a codes of your view and controller

Answer (score 1):

Next to you where clause use .ToList() and also declare either var list = or list

Answer (score 1):

The Linq `Where` method returns a list of matching entities.  You are trying to return it to a variable defined as a single entity.  If you define `eventCalendar` as type `IQueryable<Models.EventCalendar>` instead of `Models.EventCalendar` the Linq statement will work.

Or, alternatively, you can define `eventCalendar` as the more robust `List<Models.EventCalendar>` and use the Linq method `ToList()` at the end of your query.  ie. `eventCalendar = db.Events_Calendars.Where(x => x.Events.Any(y => y.End >= DateTime.Today)).ToList();`

Comment: Unfortunatly it would not be work, because `Events_Calendars.Where` returns `IQueryable<Models.EventCalendar>`. The `where` result should be casted, for example, to `List` or to other IEnumerable.

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria Well spotted.  I have fixed my answer.