# MVC Core IEnumerable Advantages over IQueryable

Tags: asp.net-core, ienumerable, iqueryable

If IQueryable has all the functions of IEnumerable, but allows additional functionalities, why even use IEnumerable?

What are the benefits of IEnumerable over IQueryable?

Reading everything here, still cannot find benefit:

[What is the difference between IQueryable and IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet)

[IEnumerable Vs IQueryable](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/732425/IEnumerable-Vs-IQueryable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware of 2 points

1. `IEnumerable<>` defines only 1 method that is `GetEnumerator()`, which means to enumerate (execute the query) immediately in the .NET program. And `IQueryable<>` has expressions and query providers which mean `IQueryable<>` is just a preparation of `IEnumerable<>` which is bound to execute by calling `GetEnumerator()` as a normal `IEnumerable<>` (Hand out the query and result back to the .NET program when finishing the external query)
2. LINQ Extension methods for `IEnumerable` take `Func<>`(delegates) parameters which mean C# functions to be executed inside the current .NET program, but `IQueryable` takes `Expression<Func<>>` parameters that mean these selectors or predicators are sealed as expressions to probably (actually indeed) be translated to external commands such as SQL queries, not going to be compiled and executed as normal C# codes.
3. Many `IQueryable<>` query providers extended additional query functions for their specified operations. Which to use depends on the actual query target.

Conclusion, `IEnumerable<>` and `IQueryable<>` have different usages, `IEnumerable<>` is for internal object queries and `IQueryable<>` is for external resource queries

Comment: this answer is a comparison;  question is again, what is advantage of IEnumerable?  if IQueryable has all advantages of IEnumerable, but allows more functionalities, why even use IEnumerable? What is advantage of IEnumerable? Does it take less memory, CPU?

Comment: IEnumerable takes function parameters, and functions can be directly called and you can specify more than 1 statement using {} on your lambda expression or just pass a method to the linq. And IQueryable just accept expressions, which mean you can just pass an simple value expression to linq, and cannot use {}, psssing method, external calling, or some other things that you can do with c# code, for the provider takes everything as code so it has to compile all your expressions to various usages and may(actually do) not support all your complex expressions

Comment: is that more just like another way of writing it, ienumerable functions vs iqueryable expressions, just trying to locate advantage

Comment: theres no advantage that you would take from. they are resolving different problems, and would be never compared by advantage

Comment: pans are for cooking and dishes are for dining, they shape similar but have different usage, and you would never want to tell why it is better dining with a dish than a pan