# Create a query step by step, should I use IEnumerable or IQueryable?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and vb.net 2017. I have 2 cases when I need to create a query step by step :

```
query = (From t in context.myobj1s select t)

if (condition1) then 
    query = query.where(Function(t2) t2.value1 < 5)
If (condition2) then 
    query = query.where(Function(t2) t2.value2 > 120)

query.tolist
```

and

```
query = (From t in context.myobj1s.Local select t)

if (condition1) then 
    query = query.where(Function(t2) t2.value1 < 5)
If (condition2) then 
    query = query.where(Function(t2) t2.value2 > 120)

Mybindingsource.Datasource = query.tolist
```

My question is: how should I declare query in each situation:

```
 Dim query as IEnumerable(of myobj1)
```

or

```
 Dim query as IQueryable(of myobj1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between IQueryable<T> and IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet), esp. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23359554/861716).

Answer (score 0):

IQueryable(of myobj1)  is preferable if you are going to use database related methods. For example, the Include(...) method is implemented based on IQueryable.

The IQueryable is extends from IEnumerable

```
public interface IQueryable<out T> : System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<out T>, System.Linq.IQueryable
```