# CS1061 IOrderedEnumerable<TEntity>' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' EF Core 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

Has ToListAsync been depricated in EntityFrameWorkCore on EF core 6?

If I use the ToList() method it works, but if I add ToListAsync I get the following erro:

'IOrderedEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' and no accessible extension method 'ToListAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'IOrderedEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Sample of the code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RainbowOF.Repositories.Common
{
    public class AppRepository<TEntity> : IAppRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        #region Privates
        private ApplicationDbContext _Context { get; set; }  // = null;
        private DbSet<TEntity> _Table = null;
        private ILoggerManager _Logger { get; }
        private IAppUnitOfWork _AppUnitOfWork { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region Initialise
        public AppRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, ILoggerManager logger, IAppUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _Context = dbContext;
            _Table = dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
            _Logger = logger;
            _AppUnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }
        #endregion

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAllOrderBy(Func<TEntity, object> orderByExpression, bool sortDesc = false)
        {
            _Logger.LogDebug($"Getting all records in Table of type: {typeof(TEntity)} order by {orderByExpression}");
            if (_AppUnitOfWork.DBTransactionIsStillRunning())
                _Logger.LogDebug("Second transaction started before current transaction completed!");
            try
            {
                var _result = sortDesc 
                    ? _Table.OrderByDescending(orderByExpression).ToList() 
                    : _Table.OrderBy(orderByExpression).ToList();
                return _result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _AppUnitOfWork.LogAndSetErrorMessage($"!!!Error Getting all (async): {ex.Message} - Inner Exception {ex.InnerException}");
#if DebugMode
                throw;     // #Debug?
#endif
            }
            return null;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            _Logger.LogDebug($"Getting all records (async) in Table of type: {typeof(TEntity)}");
            if (_AppUnitOfWork.DBTransactionIsStillRunning())
                _Logger.LogDebug("Second transaction started before current transaction completed!");
            try
            {
                var _result =  await _Table.ToListAsync();
                return _result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _AppUnitOfWork.LogAndSetErrorMessage($"!!!Error Getting all (async): {ex.Message} - Inner Exception {ex.InnerException}");
#if DebugMode
                throw;     // #Debug?
#endif
            }
            return null;
        }

//--> the above works fine, below gives the error.


        public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllOrderByAsync(Func<TEntity, object> orderByExpression, bool sortDesc = false)
        {
            _Logger.LogDebug($"Getting all records (async) in Table of type: {typeof(TEntity)} order by {orderByExpression}");
            if (_AppUnitOfWork.DBTransactionIsStillRunning())
                _Logger.LogDebug("Second transaction started before current transaction completed!");
            try
            {
                var _result = sortDesc 
                    ? await _Table.OrderByDescending(orderByExpression).ToListAsync() 
                    : await _Table.OrderBy(orderByExpression).ToListAsync();
                return _result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _AppUnitOfWork.LogAndSetErrorMessage($"!!!Error Getting all (async) order by: {ex.Message} - Inner Exception {ex.InnerException}");
#if DebugMode
                throw;     // #Debug?
#endif
            }
            return null;
        }
```

I have tried adding  in the above.

I Google and a few tickets said Async is added in 6, and some suggested adding "using System.Data.Entity;" to the usings.
If I add using System.Data.Entity; then that error goes away, but then I get conflicts with EntityFrameworkCore.

The project has been upgraded to .net 6 in VS2022. It was working in .net 5

Perhaps I am confusing technologies.

Comment: By using that *anti*pattern you broke EF Core. All that code does nothing more than what EF Core and LINQ already do, except it doesn't work. A DbContext is *already* a multi-entity Unito-of-Work, a DbSet is *already* a single-entity repository. Entities, not tables. Don't rush to "fix" assumed problems until you understand if there's anything to fix

Comment: There are several problems in this code but the one that causes the error is that LINQ works with expressions, not lambdas. The `GetAllAsync` method isn't useful though - nobody wants to load an entire table into memory, especially when EF Core. The server can query and filter data thousands of times faster than any client.

Comment: Another very serious problem: that `DBTransactionIsStillRunning` means UoW is actually broken. EF Core doesn't need database transactions because, again, DbContext *already is* a Unit of Work. All changes are cached and persisted atomically when `SaveChanges` is used. If you have to use a database transaction, something is seriously wrong. Do you call `SaveChanges` after every `Insert` or `Update`? That's doubly broken, because that `Insert` will apply *any* pending change, including DELETEs and UPDATEs.

Comment: Read carefully [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for this. I am self-taught and it shows. I am using a repository to allow for different implementations with the same interface. I did quite a lot of reading about the pros and cons of having a Repo layer and after doing the tutorial on the .net site and Pragim Tech I felt that was the most common solution. I added the DBTransaction check to try and capture any async errors in the code. So that I can pick up which calls are issues. Probably can remove it. The GetAllAsync at the moment is used for small drop down lists, that is why I need the order by.

Comment: We are all self taught. The trick is starting from the *actual* docs tutorials of a product. Other online tutorials are quite often *very* bad - the good authors aren't free. The bad authors will just copy each other (it's cheaper this way) giving the impression something is "common". You always need to understand *why* you're doing what you're doing.

Comment: If you want to load data for a dropdown list you don't need EF Core *at all*. You only need to load the values and map them to objects. To do that you can use eg [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) to directly map query results to object with eg `var lookups=connection.Query<Lookup>("select id, name from someTable where CategoryID=@category",new {category=5});`. In that case abstracting the Dapper code is useful, but what you really need is a lookup service, not a lookup repository. If you want to *edit*, EF Core is useful again

Comment: Another crucial think to consider. DbContext is disconnected. It doesn't need a connection until it has to either read or write data. All changes are cached until `SaveChanges` is called. When that happens a connection opens and all changes are persisted in a single transaction. Nothing is locked in the meantime. This has ***huge*** scaleability benefits. The copy/pasta way of creating a "unit-of-work" by using an explicit database transaction though can quickly result in conflicts with even a couple of concurrent operations and even deadlocks.

Comment: Disconnected operations and optimistic concurrency are the default in all Microsoft stacks since the late 1990s - ADO first introduced disconnected recordsets, ADO.NET had DataSets and DataTables, EF and EF Core have DbContext and SaveChanges. All changes are cached, so if you want to discard them, just don't save them. Using explicit transactions actually eliminates 20 years of performance improvements

Comment: Thanks, so essentially we remove the data repo layer/ I was keen to try only use EF syntax, I see you use SQL in the query above. It will take many changes since I am 30% done in my project (for my/our own use), but changes now is not a bad thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`OrderBy<TSource,TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,TKey>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-6.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_OrderBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) which accepts `Func` is a method defined for `IEnumerable` which does not have async version of `ToList`.

You need [`OrderBy<TSource,TKey>(IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource,TKey>>))`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.orderby?view=net-6.0#System_Linq_Queryable_OrderBy__2_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___) which is defined for `IQueryable` which is extended with [`ToListAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.tolistasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_QueryableExtensions_ToListAsync__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Threading_CancellationToken_) (you also want it because `IQueryable` overloads are actually translated into SQL while `IEnumerable` ones will fetch all the data to the client side and sort it on there). So change your method signature to accept expression of func (`Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>`) not just func:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllOrderByAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> orderByExpression, bool sortDesc = false)
{
    ...
}
```

Extra info:

- [Exrpression vs Func](https://stackoverflow.com/a/793584/2501279)
- [IQueryable vs IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet)

Comment: Thanks for this, I am a little confused as when I used Expression on the none async it failed. I struggle to call the function with a linq expression. I have got the routine in the repo to work, just struggling with using it in code behind. It is giving me problems with TKey, which I am not sure how to use. Thanks for the help I really appreciate it.