# ValueTuple in Select Linq

Tags: c#, linq, valuetuple

Good day, I have a problem, I need to pull out from query several values

```
var val= context.tab1.Select(x=> new {x.a,x.b,x.c});
```

but variable `val` will have anonymous type and because of that I cant complete my task. My next idea was get variables and put them into Tuple, but its not comfortable because I cant name values in Tuple in Select state

```
var val1= context.tab1.Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.a, x.b, x.c) );
```

After all of that i got a question is a way to put values from linq Select in ValueTuple?
I think it must look like what

```
var val2= context.tab1.Select(x => (int,int,DateTime) (x.a, x.b, x.c));
```

Sorry for my bad English and thanks

```
var val= context.tab1.Select(x=> new {x.a,x.b,x.c});
```

```
var val1= context.tab1.Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.a, x.b, x.c) );
```

```
var val2= context.tab1.Select(x => (int,int,DateTime) (x.a, x.b, x.c)) ;
```

Comment: There is ValueTuple.Create<T1, T2, T3>() method you can use .

Comment: Why not define a `class` or `record`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add a method like this:

```
static (int a, int b, DateTime c) GetValueTuple(int i1, int i2, DateTime dt) 
     => (i1, i2, dt);
```

you can change t1...tn arbitrary.

```
var val2 = context.tab1.Select(x => GetValuTuple(x.a, x.b, x.c));
```

You can use First() to ensure that it works.

```
var val3 = val2.First();
```

Comment: Yes, I do; it works. I tried @GuruStron

Comment: Why it should be worked before `Enumerate`? It doesn't make sense. @GuruStron

Comment: Yes, you are right, this will work and EF should be able to translate it in final projection. Tough it will not work in other places.

Comment: Yes, but thanks for your notice @GuruStron

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code samples referencing `context` I assume you are talking about some ORM like Entity Framework which uses not just "simple" LINQ-to-Objects but performs SQL generation based on combination of [`IQueryable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable-1?view=net-8.0) interface which uses [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/expression-trees/).

If yes - then no, currently it is not possible to create value tuples via "standard" syntax because it is not possible to use value tuples literals in the expression trees. You can monitor following issues/discussions at the github:

- [[Proposal]: Expression tree evolution](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/4727)
- [Expression trees support for tuples.](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12897)

If you really want to you can transform your `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable` and the select to a value tuple:

```
var result = (await _context.tab1
   .Select(x => new {x.a, x.b})
   .ToListAsync())
   .Select(ac => (ac.a, ac.a))
   .ToList();
```

Or

```
var result = _context.tab1
   .Select(x => new {x.a, x.b})
   .AsEnumerable()
   .Select(ac => (ac.a, ac.a))
   .ToList();
```

Or via method indirection as [@iman safari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75961891/2501279) suggests.

But I would argue that in any case is a bit pointless, because creating a new type with [records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) is very easy with modern .NET. So just create a type and use it.

Read also:

- [What is the difference between IQueryable and IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet)
- [How Queries Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/how-query-works) in EF Core