# LINQ Query FirstOrDefault speed

Tags: c#, sql, linq

When having a query like this

```
var id = 1;
var query = (from c in cTable.Where(x => x.Id == id)
             from a in aTable.Where(x => x.Code == c.Code).DefaultIfEmpty()  
             select new Object()
                 {
                     Id = c.Id,
                     Code = c.Code,
                 }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Does the query search first all the c where Id is equal to id and then retrieve the first one with FirstOrDefault(), or does the query already stop at the first c found?

If it doesn't stop searching until the end (and then apply the FirstOrDefault), is there a way to let the query stop at the first found?

Comment: Have you looked at the generated sql query? For entity framework you can use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1412902/284240

Comment: This is going to depend a lot on how exactly cTable and aTable are defined and obtained (although it should still short-circuit when a match is found, even in the worst outcomes)

Comment: It depend on How U defind Ur Table 
U can  Check ur query  by MSSM - > XEvent profiler -> Tsql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It hugely depends on what `cTable` and `aTable` are. Since your question is tagged with SQL also I would assume that both are some `IQueryable`s and you are using some ORM, so in this case the LINQ query is "just" translated into SQL and executed by the database engine and it is up to the DB how it executes the query. For example the latest EF Core generates something like the following query:

```sql
SELECT a."Id", a."Code"
FROM "cTable" AS a
LEFT JOIN "aTable" AS p ON a."Code" = p."Code"
WHERE a."Id" = @__id_0
LIMIT 1
```

To analyze the execution plan you will need to use the database specific tools and see how the query is processed.

As for LINQ-to-Objects (i.e. `cTable` and `aTable` for example are in-memory collections like `List`s or arrays) just insert a side effect:

```cs
var query = (from c in cTable.Where(x =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Filter cTable: {x}");
        return x.Id == id;
    })
    from a in aTable.Where(x =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Filter aTable: {x}");
        return x.Code == c.Code;
    }).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        Id = c.Id,
        Code = c.Code,
    })
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that this is an implementation detail but currently "on my machine" it searches for the first matching element of 1st collection (`cTable`) and then scans through the second one (`aTable`).

Read more:

- [What is the difference between IQueryable and IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet)
- [EF Core: How Queries Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/how-query-works)
- To see the query in EF Core you can use `ToQueryString` (move everything before the `FirstOrDefault()` to a variable and call `ToQueryString` on it) or logging - [Overview of Logging and Interception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/#simple-logging)

Comment: Using ToQueryString() it returns this text "There is no query string because the in-memory provider does not use a string-based query language."
What does it mean?

Comment: @Steve It looks like for some reason you are using [EF Core In-Memory Database Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli).