# EF Core async LINQ Where(predicate).ToListAsync() Error: CS1061 IEnumerable does not contain ToListAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So I have a context class `EFCoreMContext` with defined property `EFCore.DBSet<AccessTime> AccessTime`

```
public class EFCoreMContext : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext
{
    public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<AccessTime> AccessTime { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then I have a repository class `CAccessTimeRepository`

```
public class CAccessTimeRepository : IRepository<AccessTime>
{
    private EFCoreMContext db;

    public CAccessTimeRepository(EFCoreMContext context)
    {
        this.db = context;
    }
    ...
```

with async functions:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<AccessTime>> FindAsync(Func<AccessTime, bool> predicate)
    {
        return await db.AccessTime.Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
    }
    ...
}
```

The trouble is when I try to use this `ToListAsync()` - Visual Studio highlights it with an error

> CS1061    IEnumerable does not contain ToListAsync()

The thing is when I use `.Where()` with something like this

```
.Where(x => x.ID == 1)
```

it returns an `IQueryable`, so I can use `ToListAsync()`. But when I use this method with my predicate, it returns `IEnumerable`.

So deal with it I try to pass this code with an `AsQueryable`

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<AccessTime>> FindAsync(Func<AccessTime, bool> predicate)
{
    return await db.AccessTime
                   .Where(predicate)
                   .AsQueryable()
                   .ToListAsync();
}
```

While executing this code I get an error:

> The source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncEnumerable<_3TierApp.DAL.Entities.AccessTime>'. Only sources that implement 'IAsyncEnumerable' can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.

I have no idea why `.Where()` with my predicate and `with x => x.Id` returns different types.

Can somebody explain? And also what will be the best working solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF Core's extensions like [`EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.tolistasync?view=efcore-7.0) work with `IQueryable` interface (check out the linked method signature), not an `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` requires `Expression<Func<...>>` ([`Queryable.Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.where?view=net-7.0) for example) not just `Func<...>` (which allows to analyze passed expression tree and generate SQL query), so change the signature accordingly:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<AccessTime>> FindAsync(
     Expression<Func<AccessTime, bool>> predicate)
{
    return await db.AccessTime
         .Where(predicate)
         .ToListAsync();
}
```

Read more:

- [What is the difference between `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet)
- [Expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/expression-trees/)
- [EF Core: How Queries Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/how-query-works)

Comment: Thanks for a fast answer! By the way, what's the difference between your answer and a `return (await db.AccessTime.ToListAsync()).Where(predicate);` where predicate is still `Func<..>`?

Comment: @BEBROID in case of EF Core mine will generate SQL query which will perform filtering on db side, while yours will fetch the whole table and perform filtering client side.