# I have a problem with a query taking too long in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a query that has more than 7k records, but it is slow and the client takes more than 30 seconds to respond.

But the view itself only takes a second to execute in SQL.

How can I improve the performance of the following code?

I have tried putting it in a view and in a stored procedure but there was no improvement. The following C# code runs too slowly, while executing the view in SQL only takes a second.

```cs
var resultadoProductos = await Context.ViewQueryProductoAlls.Where(a => !a.Delet).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

if (model.Producto != null)
{
    resultadoProductos = resultadoProductos
        .Where(a => a.IdProducto.ToString().ToLower().Contains(model.Producto.ToString().ToLower())).ToList();
}

if (model.NombreProducto != null)
{
    resultadoProductos = resultadoProductos
        .Where(a => a.Producto.ToString().ToLower().Contains(model.NombreProducto.ToString().ToLower())).ToList();
}

if (model.Id != null)
{
    resultadoProductos = resultadoProductos.Where(a => a.Id == model.Id).ToList();
}

if (model.categoriaId != null)
{
    resultadoProductos = resultadoProductos.Where(a => a.IdCategoria == model.categoriaId).ToList();
}

if (model.PrecioDesde != null)
{
    resultadoProductos = resultadoProductos.Where(a => a.Precio >= model.PrecioDesde).ToList();
}

if (model.PrecioHasta != null)
{
    resultadoProductos = resultadoProductos.Where(a => a.Precio >= model.PrecioHasta).ToList();
}

var query = resultadoProductos.Select(x => new ProductoDTOList.DetalleProducto
{
    Id = x.Id,
    IdSucursal = x.IdSucursal,
    Sucursal = x.Sucursal,
    IdProducto = x.IdProducto,
    IdCategoria = x.IdCategoria,
    Categoria = x.Categoria,
    IdSubCategorias = Context.MaestraCategoria.Where(b => b.IdProducto == x.IdProducto && b.Delet == false)
        .Select(a => a.IdSubcategoria).FirstOrDefault(),
    IdUnidad = x.IdUnidad,
    Unidad = x.Unidad,
    IdEstado = x.IdEstado,
    Estado = x.Estado,
    CantidadProductoDisponible = x.CantidadProductoDisponible,
    IdModena = 1,
    Moneda = "RD$",
    Precio = x.Precio,
    Costo = (decimal)x.Costo,
    Producto = x.Producto,
    ProductoComentario = x.ProductoComentario,
    ListaImagenes = GetImagesProductoByColor(x.IdProducto),
    ConsultarImagenesDistinct = GetImagesProductoByColorDistint(x.IdProducto),
    Descuentos = GetDescuentosProducto(x.IdProducto),
    CarasteristicaColorSize = GetCarasteristicaProductoColor(x.Id),
    MeGusta = GetMeGusta(model.CodigoCliente, x.Id)
});

if (model.DescuentoDesde != null)
{
    query = query.Where(a => a.Descuentos.Any(b => b.Descuento >= model.DescuentoDesde)).ToList();
}

if (model.DescuentoHasta != null)
{
    query = query.Where(a => a.Descuentos.Any(b => b.Descuento <= model.DescuentoHasta)).ToList();
}

if (model.carasteristicas != null)
{
    query = query.Where(a => a.CarasteristicaColorSize.Any(b => model.carasteristicas.Contains(b.Size))).ToList();
}

Result.TotalRecord = resultadoProductos.Count();
Result.Skip = model.NumeroPagina;
Result.Take = model.CantidadRows;

Result.DataList = query.Skip((model.NumeroPagina - 1) * model.CantidadRows).Take(model.CantidadRows).ToList();
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also, please do not put non-code in a code fence. Code fences are for code or when fixed width characters are important.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for query tuning advice, however, does not include the queries or code (in EF) being run, the DDL for the objects involved, along with their indexes, or the query plan in a consumable format (such as by using [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)). It therefore lacks any information to be able to performance tune their code.

Comment: There are multiple important differences between the C# / Linq queries that you are complaining are too slow versus the `SELECT` statement you have shown as your baseline for performance comparison -- which means that it is not really a fair comparison.  Consider just this one difference: your C# / Linq queries depend on `.Contains()` conditions, which are very expensive in terms of performance versus your `SELECT` which does not utilize any filter / Where conditions.

Comment: Though you claim that there is only 7k non-deleted records in the database (i.e. 
what will be returned by `Context.ViewQueryProductoAlls.Where(a => !a.Delet)...ToListAsync()`).

Comment: @ThomA _"because it is asking for query tuning advice"_ -  actually it is not, problem is not with query, at least in the provided code, check out my answer.

Comment: @GuruStron at the time I VTC'd the question was a [significantly different state](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76885027/1), with images of code, and text in code fences.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that you should definitely not do is to call `ToList` on every filter operation. Enumerables are lazy and their execution is deferred and you should leverage that, and you definitely should leverage the dynamic query building capabilities, i.e. try something like:

```
IQueryable<ViewQueryProducto> query = await Context.ViewQueryProductoAlls.Where(a => !a.Delet).AsNoTracking();

if (model.Producto != null)
{
    query = query.Where(a => a.IdProducto.ToString().ToLower().Contains(model.Producto.ToString().ToLower()));
}
if (model.NombreProducto != null)
{
    query = query.Where(a => a.Producto.ToString().ToLower().Contains(model.NombreProducto.ToString().ToLower()));
}
//....

var result = await query.Select(...).ToListAsync()
```

You current code fetches all the non-deleted products into memory and then performs filtering client side (i.e. the `await Context.ViewQueryProductoAlls.Where(a => !a.Delet).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync()` call).

But the biggest problem is the following:

```
var query = resultadoProductos.Select(x => new ProductoDTOList.DetalleProducto
{
    // ...
    IdSubCategorias = Context.MaestraCategoria
        .Where(b => b.IdProducto == x.IdProducto && b.Delet == false)
        .Select(a => a.IdSubcategoria)
        .FirstOrDefault(),

   // ...
}
```

Which will result in the database query per `resultadoProductos` (so 7k queries if there are 7k products).

You need to rewrite the code so EF Core will issue one query (or constant number if something like `AsSplitQuery()` is used) for all needed data and then process it server side.

Please read:

- [What is the difference between IQueryable<T> and IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/252785/2501279)
- [How Queries Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/how-query-works)
- [Filtered include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) can be used too.