# What is the Execution Location for the below Snippet?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, ienumerable

Explain the location of each operation i.e WHERE and TAKE.
**In Memory or on  Database side** for both IEnumerable and IQueryable.

```
IEnumerable<Student> listStudents = DBContext.Students.Where(x => x.Gender == "Male");
listStudents = listStudents.Take(2);

foreach (var std in listStudents)
{
    Console.WriteLine(std.FirstName + " " + std.LastName);
}
```

```
IQueryable<Student> listStudents = DBContext.Students
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where(x => x.Gender == "Male");
listStudents = listStudents.Take(2);

foreach (var std in listStudents)
{
    Console.WriteLine(std.FirstName + " " + std.LastName);
}
```

Comment: In both cases it will take place in the database. You aren't enumerating the query before the Where or Take

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel I have updated the Enumeration part. What about now ?

Comment: The fact that a query returns an `IEnumerable` does NOT mean that the query has been enumerated. It means that it CAN be enumerated. As @TN said, you need to read up on what `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` actually are, and it should become clearer

Comment: @TN, after going though a lot of articles, this confusion arose. Normally, they say IEnumerable operations are executed in memory. But as per some articles, for IEnumerable only the `Take part` for the mentioned code will be executed in memory.

Comment: I am more concerned about the Where and Take operations locations for both snippets.

Comment: *A side questions for others reading this: Am I wrong or does `.AsQueryable()` do next-to-nothing in the above code, since `DBContext.Students` is already an `IQueryable<>` (since it is presumably a `DbSet<>`)?*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `DBContext.Students` is `DbSet<Student>` then for the first snippet EF should translate `Where` into SQL but `Take` will be performed on the client side when/if materialization will happen. The second snippet should result in both `Where` and `Take` translated into appropriate SQL. Note that actual difference would not be that big - both queries should not fetch extra data (since only `Take(2)` is "different" and you don't need to fetch more than 2 elements either way). But if you will rewrite the first snippet to something like:

```
IEnumerable<Student> listStudents = DBContext.Students;
listStudents = listStudents
    .Where(x => x.Gender == "Male")
    .Take(2);
```

Then it can potentially lead to extra data fetched to the client since the filtering will be done on the client side too (i.e. you will need to fetch data until 2 "Male"s are encountered and depending on the ordering used by the DB it potentially can return a lot of non-"Male"s).

All of this can be easily tested with EF Core by [enabling logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/#simple-logging) which will output the executed queries and other info (also note the [`EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToQueryString(IQueryable)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.toquerystring?view=efcore-7.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions_ToQueryString_System_Linq_IQueryable_) available since EF Core 5th version).

Read also:

- [What is the difference between IQueryable<T> and IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet)
- [EF Core docs: How Queries Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/how-query-works)