# EF Core - Filtering query on C# method (buffering vs streaming)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, filtering, asenumerable

**Scenario**

I have this code (simplified):

```cs
var query = _context.Products
                    .Where(x => x.IsActive)
                    .Select(x => new ProductDto 
                                 {
                                     Id = x.Id,
                                     Name = x.Name,
                                     Description = GetDescription(x)
                                 });

// Building predicates (using LinqKit)
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();

query = query.Where(predicate);

var count = await query.CountAsync();
var list = await query.ToListAsync();
```

And it works when I filter by Id, Name. The issue arises when I want to filter by `Description`, eg:

```cs
query = query.Where(x => x.Description.Contains("winter"));
```

Here an exception is thrown - Linq cannot translate this into SQL - understandable.

**Question**

How do you think I could handle this? This is how I have built my filtering/sorting, etc., and I want to keep it this way. How can I filter/sort by properties that use the C# method that cannot be translated into SQL?

**What I tried**

After reading this [Efficient Querying EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-querying#buffering-and-streaming) I got an idea that maybe this is the way to go.

I tried to do it this way:

```cs
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();

var enumerable = query.AsEnumerable();

enumerable = enumerable.Where(predicate);

// I convert it back to Queryable to use things such as 
// Take() and Skip() hoping it will be translated into SQL
query = enumerable.AsQueryable();

// Here I lost the ability to use "Async"
var count = query.Count();
var list = query.ToList();
```

And it seems to kind of work. I lost the ability to filter on the SQL level (but I may be able to separate which filters to apply at what stage), but I'm not sure how it works.

I think I understand the difference between buffering and streaming - here I do not load all the results to the memory - I expect streaming to happen. When inspecting DB calls - only single calls are made (with `.Count()` and `.ToList()`) which sounds good.

Is it a valid way to approach the problem? How exactly does filtering work after `.AsEnumerable()`? How does Linq know what to do with the `GetDescription(x)` if it neither loads it into memory nor sends a request to the database?

// Edit for more context:
I might have simplified too much, sorry about that. My GetDescription method looks like this:

```cs
public static string GetDescription(int productType)
{
    switch (productType)
    {
        case 0:
            return ProductTypeEnum.Value1.GetDescription();
        case 1:
            return ProductTypeEnum.Value2.GetDescription();
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

and I use it in the query in such a way:

```cs
Description  = x.ProductType != null ? GetDescription(x.ProductType) : string.Empty
```

**Post-thoughts after resolving the issue**
I misunderstood how queries are translated. The fact misled me, that without filtering by problematic property - everything worked fine. I thought it meant that it is evaluated on the server side and translated into SQL. What was happening was that this property was marked to be evaluated on the client side, once the records were fetched.

If your query cannot be translated into SQL - first make sure the query is well written, cause it's probably not.

Comment: Show us your `GetDescription(x)` function.

Comment: `AsQueryable()` here is useless, the query will not be partially translated to sql before `AsEnumerable` and after `AsQueryable`. you will just fetch everything into memory (twice) and and perform all operations   on the client side.

Comment: `Linq cannot translate this into SQL` fix the query then. There's no "buffering vs streaming". If you can't generate the correct SQL query you'll have to load all objects in memory and only then process it using LINQ-to-Objects

Comment: As for the error, that's caused by `GetDescription(x)`, not `x.Description.Contains("winter")`. What does that method do? Does it concatenate other properties perhaps? In that case you can fix the original problem by filtering each property instead of their combination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think I understand the difference between buffering and streaming

Difference here is between client-side evaluation and server-side evaluation.

> Is it a valid way to approach the problem?

Arguably - no.

> How exactly does filtering work after `.AsEnumerable()`?

Everything "before" will be converted to SQL and performed on the database side, everything after will be handled on the client side (in-memory) i.e. for `Count` all matching rows will be fetched into memory, `GetDescription` will be called on them and then filtering will happen and then items will be counted. Then you will fetch and filter all the same items again for `ToList`. Note that  EF Core can call custom functions in final projection (i.e. last `Select`) without moving to much to client side. EF Core also can handle filtering on the projection properties if they were created via translatable code (i.e. one that does not use client-side functions like `GetDescription`). Also note that `GetDescription(x)` should result in fetching all the columns of the table.

> How does Linq know what to do with the GetDescription(x) if it neither loads it into memory nor sends a request to the database?

LINQ-to-Objects will be used which will just call the method

> When inspecting DB calls - only single calls are made

I wonder how you did that and what queries you have seen. Try enabling [simple logging for EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging) and checking the logs.

What you can do depends heavily on the `GetDescription`. You can provide a [user defined function mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping) which should make it translatable. Or do something like:

```
var query = _context.Products
   .Where(x => x.IsActive)
   .Where(x => x.DescriptionPartColumn1.Contains("winter") 
       || x.DescriptionPartColumn1.Contains("winter"))
   .Select(x => new ProductDto ...)
```

Also I recommend to check out:

- [What is the difference between IQueryable<T> and IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/252785/2501279)
- [EF Core docs: Client vs. Server Evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval)
- [EF Core docs: How Queries Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/how-query-works)

**UPD**

Just inline the `GetDescription` function:

```
var query = _context.Products
   .Where(x => x.IsActive)
   .Select(x => new ProductDto
   {
       //...
       Description = x.ProductType == 0
           ? "This is one Desc"
           :  x.ProductType == 1 
                 ? "This is two Desc" 
                 : string.Empty
   })
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is the call to `GetDescription`. EF Core cannot translate your custom function.

Your use of `AsEnumerable` is a bad idea, it will make it retrieve *all* rows from the server and filter it in memory.

Instead, you need to make it return an `IQueryable`

```cs
public static IQueryable<ProductDto> AsProductDto(this IQueryable<Product> query, int productType)
{
    return query.Select(x =>
        new ProductDto 
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Description =
                x.ProductType == 0 ? "someDescrip" :   // use hard-coded literals, do not call functions
                x.ProductType == 1 ? "otherDescrip" :
                ""
        });
}
```

You can then do:

```cs
var query = _context.Products
                    .Where(x => x.IsActive)
                    .AsProductDto();

query = query.Where(x => x.Description.Contains("winter"));
```

Note that calling `.Count` and `.ToList` is inefficient. Pull it into a list if you need it, then just check the count and that list.