# Why does the value of a method doesn't change inside select method?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have a method that return value from sequence in Postgres:

```
public long GetSId(DatabaseFacade d, string sequenceName)
{
    var result = new NpgsqlParameter(":result", NpgsqlDbType.Integer)
    {
        Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.InputOutput,
        Value = 0
    };
    d.ExecuteSqlRaw($"SELECT nextval('{sequenceName}')", result);
    return (long)result.Value;
}
```

And I have a method to form data:

```
private List<CrossingsResult> FormCrossingResult()
{
    var d = _dbContext.Database;
    var crosswalks = _dbContext.Crosswalks
        .Select(x => new CrossingsResult
        {
            SId = GetSId(d, _sequenceName),
            ...
        }).ToList();
    return crosswalks;
```

The problem is when I call the method inside Select the SId doesn't change (for example, it will put for all records SId same value). But if I call the method outside crosswalk it works
Like here:

```
private List<CrossingsResult> FormCrossingResult()
{
    var d = _dbContext.Database;
    Console.WriteLine($"First call: {GetSId(d, _sequenceName)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Second call: {GetSId(d, _sequenceName)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Third call: {GetSId(d, _sequenceName)}");
    var crosswalks = _dbContext.Crosswalks
        .Select(x => new CrossingsResult
        {
            SId = GetSId(d, _sequenceName),
            ...
        }).ToList();
    foreach (var crosswalk in crosswalks)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(crosswalk.SId);
    }
    return crosswalks;
```

Result be like this:
[image: Console output]

I tried to make it with for loop and it works:

```
private List<CrossingsResult> FormCrossingResult()
{
    var d = _dbContext.Database;
    var crosswalks = _dbContext.Crosswalks
        .Select(x => new CrossingsResult
        {
            ...
        }).ToList();
    foreach (var crosswalk in crosswalks)
    {
        crosswalk.SId = GetSId(d, _sequenceName);
    }
    return crosswalks;
```

But I want the method called inside Select and to make it without using for loop

Comment: 1) I don't use C#, so I don't understand all that is going here. I will guess that `var crosswalks = _dbContext.Crosswalks  .Select(x => new CrossingsResult ...` is grabbing a value for a given database session and then using that 'frozen' value in `foreach (var crosswalk in crosswalks) ...`. Whereas the loop version is getting a fresh value each time through the loop. See [Sequence Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html). 2) To confirm look at the Postgres log.

Comment: Must be related to a difference in the way the `Select` translation of the Linq-Provider handles the PG nextval function as compared to invoking `nextval` outside that context.
Seems that these single calls to GetSId consume one ID value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I converted Crosswalks to a list and then used the select method:

```
private List<CrossingsResult> FormCrossingResult()
{
    var d = _dbContext.Database;
    var crosswalks = _dbContext.Crosswalks
        .ToList() // here
        .Select(x => new CrossingsResult
        {
            SId = GetSId(d, _sequenceName),
            ...
        }).ToList();
    return crosswalks;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would start from that this looks suspiciously close to being a [The XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

As for what is happening here. I can't pinpoint at the moment why exactly (i.e. docs/source code) it behaves like that but the reason is basically is the following - EF Core will translate your LINQ code into SQL and `GetSId` is obviously is not a translatable function from EF Core point of view (it is just some "random" user-defined one). But EF Core is a bit smart and it can handle some untranslatable parts in the final projection (i.e. `Select` in this case).  If you will add a side effect to the function:

```
public long GetSId(DatabaseFacade d, string sequenceName)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"get seq: {sequenceName}");
   // ...
}
```

You will see that the function is called only a single time. This is caused by the fact that function is not actually using any data from the processed entity (and it is the part I can't explain with docs/source code). If you change the function to something like (for demonstration purposes):

```
public long GetSId(object dummyData, DatabaseFacade d, string sequenceName)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"get seq: {sequenceName}");
    return Random.Shared.Next();
}
```

And will change the call to:

```
var crosswalks = _dbContext.Crosswalks
    .Select(x => new CrossingsResult
    {
        SId = GetSId(x.SomeProp // dummy prop to change translation
            , d
            , _sequenceName),
        ...
    })
    .ToList();
```

You will see that `GetSId` will be invoked several times as expected. But actually calling database from the same context will fail since you will already have an operation running on it.

As a quick fix you can go with the `foreach` approach you have but in general I would recommend to consider some other approach, for example defining a stored procedure to fetch all the data or maybe using [EF Core ability to provide user-defined function mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping).

See also:

- [What is the difference between `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet)
- [EF Core: How Queries Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/how-query-works)